# Scare of My Life With GIT: I've got no branch!

Tags: git, branch

I had checked out an old hash (commit) and was working on it, checking in merrily and ignoring warnings that I wasn't working in a branch. Then I switched to a branch and realized that I had **no way to get back to my orphaned checkins** (luckily I had the terminal window open still, so I checked it out and branched).

How can I get GIT to tell me the names of the commits that do NOT belong to a branch? Or just all the commits, if that's not possible...

Comment: "checking in merrily and ignoring warnings". Well, that goes to show: You can ignore warnings, but you should know what you are doing :-).

Comment: 1.5 years later, reading the question and answers over, I don't think it goes to show that at all, but perhaps the opposite: eventually it will all be clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git) which has a great explanation of how to find stashes you've dropped. You can see dangling commits etc. the same way.

Comment: Man that is awesome. I don't use stash yet but it opens the door. Thanks John.

Comment: Oh man, you'll never stop once you learn it. Stashing changes to try them on different branches, to test merges, to switch between three different versions of a change, to get rid of half your change without losing the other half forever...

Comment: never saw your comment here because it had no @yar in it :)... anyway, yes, I'm still learning new stuff on GIT daily

Answer (score 7):

`git reflog` will show the log of the references created by recent activity you've done.  For future reference, `git checkout` of a commit puts you on an [detached head](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#_detached_head).  If you want to base work on an old commit, you should create a branch off of that commit instead.

```
git checkout -b newbranch oldsha1
```

or

```
git branch newbranch oldsha1
git checkout newbranch
```

Comment: Thanks! That's in fact how I got back, but without `git reflog` it was just luck

Answer (score 2):

You can fish them out of the reflog, which stores the commits which you've had checked out.

`git reflog` will print out the most recent commits pointed to by HEAD, which is your working copy.

You can also get a list of all objects in your tree which are unreachable from your current branches using `git fsck`.

Comment: Excellent, git fsck is interesting, hadn't even heard of that.