# Unable to extract revision information from commit

Tags: git, git-svn

Just noticed a scary problem with git svn (git version 1.6.5.2).
First commiting my work as normal with `git commit`, when finished I did `git svn dcommit`.
This started fine with `Resetting to the latest refs/remotes/git-svn` but then failed and returned the error `Unable to extract revision information  from commit`.

This left all files that changed in between the last svn dcommit and the current git version unstaged and all git log messages in between are also gone.

**Now, is there a way to get the git commits with log messages back?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `git reflog`, one of the last entries in there will point to the commit you are looking for.

If all else fails, you can use [the recover-anything approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git/91795#91795).