# Can I recover a branch after its deletion in Git?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

If I run `git branch -d XYZ`, is there a way to recover the branch? Is there a way to go back as if I didn't run the delete branch command?

Comment: A really awesome note to make about the accepted answer is that it works even if the branch was deleted in origin! I just recovered several branches that I did not have locally anymore after they were accidentally deleted in origin.

Answer (score 2889, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do `git reflog --no-abbrev` and find the SHA1 for the commit at the tip of your deleted branch, then just `git checkout [sha]`. And once you're at that commit, you can just `git checkout -b [branchname]` to recreate the branch from there.

---

**Credit to @Cascabel for this condensed/one-liner version and @Snowcrash for how to obtain the sha.**

If you've just deleted the branch you'll see something like this in your terminal `Deleted branch <your-branch> (was <sha>)`. Then just use that `<sha>` in this one-liner:

```
git checkout -b <your-branch> <sha>
```

Comment: For any folks who did the deletion from SourceTree rather than command line, you can find out your SHA1 by going to View -> Show Command History.  Find the Deleting branch command and look for the "Deleted branch <branch-name> (was <sha>)" message.

Comment: For GitKraken: take a look at the Activity Log and you should see an entry like this: `Delete ref <branch> at <sha>: finished.`

Comment: Once I've done `git checkout [sha]`, git suggested me to do ` git switch -c <new_branch_name>` ... I think that it does the same of `git checkout -b <your-branch> <sha>` ... maybe it's a new command?!

Comment: @funder7 `git switch` has been a thing for a few years :P "switch to this branch, creating before switching"

Comment: Oh...okay! :-D I'll try to remember this command, I'm too accustomed to checkout -b!

Comment: I wanted to rename `master` into `main` then merge changes from `dev` . My `dev` branch was automatically deleted because of renaming `master` to `dev` by mistake (because an existing branch already had this name). This solved my issue.

Comment: This really saved my bacon.

Comment: Can someone accidentally delete the main branch? I'm deleting completed branches and I see the option to delete 'origin/main" or "origin/master".

Comment: I was having heart issues till I found this answer. My heart is fine now.

Comment: when using <code>git branch -D branch-name</code>

Comment: To locate SHA of the **hard** deleted branch, you will be notified as `Deleted branch <branch-name> (was c9d72ea4)` Here **c9d72ea4** is the SHA key. Then use `git reflog --no-abbrev` and find for your deleted branch SHA key. Once you locate it, just checkout it and create a new branch from this point. Adding one more thing here, that if there are multiple commits with same SHA key then go for last commit only. Prefer commit having `HEAD@{1}` to `HEAD@{2}`.

Comment: step one should be: [git disable automatic garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28092485/how-to-prevent-garbage-collection-in-git) with `git config --global gc.auto 0`

Answer (score 295):

## (Re)Creating the branch ONCE you've got the commit hash

You will do it use this command to create the new branch on the specified commit hash:

```
git branch <my-new-branch-name> <commit-hash>
```

But the hardest part is to find the commit hash and you will have 2 options explained just below:

---

## Finding the commit hash with the command line

### When the commit hash is in the `reflog`

Most of the time unreachable commits are in the `reflog` (that keeps track of a lot of git changes). So, **the first thing to try is to look at the reflog** using the command `git reflog` (which displays the reflog for `HEAD`).

Perhaps something easier is to use the command `git reflog name-of-my-branch` if the commit was part of a specific and still existing branch. It also works with a remote e.g. if you had force pushed (though one should use `git push --force-with-lease` instead which prevents mistakes and is more recoverable).

---

### When the commit hash is NOT in the `reflog`

If your commits are not in your reflog (perhaps they were deleted by a 3rd party tool that doesn't write to the reflog), you may try this command first to create a file with all the dangling commits

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt
```

then read the SHA of the missing commit and reset you branch to it.

Frequent users may create the alias `git rescue` using

```
git config --global alias.rescue '!git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt'
```

---

Here are some examples showing how to analyze the found commits

Display commit metadata (author, creation date and commit message):

```
git cat-file -p 48540dfa438ad8e442b18e57a5a255c0ecad0560
```

Also see diffs:

```
git log -p 48540dfa438ad8e442b18e57a5a255c0ecad0560
```

Create a branch on the found commit:

```
git branch commit_rescued 48540dfa438ad8e442b18e57a5a255c0ecad0560
```

---

## Using [GitExtensions](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) GUI on Windows

Similarly to what you can do from the command line, you can take the commit hash from the reflog or from dangling commits:

### From the reflog (1st thing to try)

You have 2 options:

- Display dangling commits in the revision grid (maybe the easiest): In the menu `View` => `Show reflog references` and you should now be able to see the dangling commits from the reflogs (the branch in grey with no branch at the tip: copy the commit hash)

  [image: Reflog displayed in revision grid]
- Access to reflog content for HEAD or another branch: In the menu `Commands` => `Show reflogs...`
  [image: reflogs]

### Finding a lost commit **not available** from the reflog

You can recover lost commits ( and also uncommitted staged files!) with via the menu `Repository` => `Git maintenance` => `Recover lost objects...`. For each commit, sorted by date, you will have the hash, the commit message and will be able to display easily the commit diff.
[image: Recover lost commits]

Related: [Easily recover deleted files that have been staged previously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853981/717372)

Comment: you are my hero, dude. thx a lot

Answer (score 67):

If you like to use a GUI, you can perform the entire operation with gitk.

```
gitk --reflog
```

This will allow you to see the branch's commit history as if the branch hadn't been deleted.  Now simply right click on the most recent commit to the branch and select the menu option `Create new branch`.

Answer (score 39):

The top voted solution does actually more than requested:

```
git checkout <sha>
git checkout -b <branch>
```

or

```
git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

move you to the new branch together with all recent changes you might have forgot to commit. This may not be your intention, especially when in the "panic mode" after losing the branch.

A **cleaner (and simpler) solution** seems to be the one-liner (after you found the `<sha>` with `git reflog`):

```
git branch <branch> <sha>
```

Now neither your current branch nor uncommited changes are affected. Instead only a new branch will be created all the way up to the `<sha>`.

If it is not the tip, it'll still work and you get a shorter branch, then you can retry with new `<sha>` and new branch name until you get it right.

Finally you can rename the successfully restored branch into what it was named or anything else:

```
git branch -m <restored branch> <final branch>
```

Needless to say, the key to success was to find the right commit `<sha>`, so name your commits wisely :)

Answer (score 37):

If you removed the branch and forgot its commit id, you can do this command:

```
git log --graph --decorate $(git rev-list -g --all)
```

After this, you'll be able to see all commits.
Then, you can do `git checkout` to this id and under this commit create a new branch.

Comment: This one allowed me to recover a couple year-old branches that none of the other methods could find. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried your command and I get a list of commits within the branch, but I want to restore the deleted branch, how can I do it?

Comment: You saved my day, thank you!!

Answer (score 26):

First type

```
git reflog
```

in the terminal.

After that, get the `HEAD@{**number**}` (e.g. `HEAD@{12}`).

Now enter:

```
git checkout -b 'branch_name' 'HEAD@{22}'
```

Comment: Simple ! Live Saver, thanks.

Comment: Life saver indeed!

Comment: short and simple!

Comment: This saved my a** for deleted branch from origin.

Answer (score 16):

Adding to [**tfe** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-the-deletion-in-git/3640806#3640806): there is also the **[git-resurrect.sh](http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob/HEAD:/contrib/git-resurrect.sh)** script in the `contrib/` area of the Git sources (in git.git repository), which might help you.

> `git-resurrect <name>` attempts to find traces of a branch tip
>   called `<name>`, and tries to resurrect it.  Currently, the reflog is
>   searched for checkout messages, and with `-r` also merge messages.  With
>   `-m` and `-t`, the history of all refs is scanned for `Merge <name> into
>   other`/`Merge <other> into <name>` (respectively) commit subjects, which
>   is rather slow but allows you to resurrect other people's topic
>   branches.

Comment: It worked for me now although I had to add /usr/lib/git-core/ to my PATH . But it didn't perform the miracle I was hoping for :(

Answer (score 15):

I used the following commands to find and retrieve my deleted branch. The first steps are from gcb's description.

```
$ git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found > lost
$ cat lost | cut -d\  -f3 > commits
$ cat commits | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline
```

Now look for the git commit id (GIT-SHA) based on the commit comments and use it in the command below. Checkout a new branch called NEW-BRANCH with the previously found GIT-SHA:

```
$ git checkout -b NEW-BRANCH GIT-SHA
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Took a little time to search the name, but the time worth it. If there is a way to also search on commit message string, would be much better.

Comment: I have same problem with the question posted above, and this answer works for me.

Answer (score 10):

From my understanding if the branch to be deleted can be reached by another branch, you can delete it safely using

```
git branch -d [branch]
```

and your work is not lost. Remember that a branch is not a snapshot, but a pointer to one. So when you delete a branch you delete a pointer.

You won't even lose work if you delete a branch which cannot be reached by another one. Of course it won't be as easy as checking out the commit hash, but you can still do it. That's why Git is unable to delete a branch which cannot be reached by using `-d`. Instead you have to use

```
git branch -D [branch]
```

This is part of a must watch video from Scott Chacon about Git. Check minute 58:00 when he talks about branches and how delete them.

[Introduction to Git with Scott Chacon of GitHub](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDR433b0HJY)

Comment: How is this helping to answer the question?

Comment: Telling the asker that branches don't hold content but are actually pointers. You don't need to be afraid of deleting branches.. you can create new ones pointing to the same commit as the deleted one.... Wow! I still remember when I askered this question. Good times back to 2012!

Comment: Had to scroll three screens to AT LAST find an answer who adresses the problem : deleting a branch is deleting a mere pointer. No data loss situation here, the only thing to recover is where was it pointing. Answers who go directly to `reflog` are just overkill.

Comment: @RomainValeri : great, so how do you recover `branch_name`  without using `reflog`?

Answer (score 10):

Thanks for all of you.

My problem was that i deleted my branch on GitLab (remotely) as well as on  GIT (locally).

but somehow i got my commits back like so:

1. first i got the last commit (SHA) with

```
git log --graph --decorate $(git rev-list -g --all)
```

2. i checkout last SHA simply

```
git checkout <SHA>
```

3. then i created a brand new branch (named as you prefer) by typing

```
git switch -c <branch-name>
```

Then i got my commits back i pushed the branch all over again

Thank god.

ps: Somehow (SHA) is a commit code

Answer (score 9):

If you don't have a reflog, eg. because you're working in a bare repository which does not have the reflog enabled and the commit you want to recover was created recently, another option is to find recently created commit objects and look through them.

From inside the `.git/objects` directory run:

```
find . -ctime -12h -type f | sed 's/[./]//g' | git cat-file --batch-check | grep commit
```

This finds all objects (commits, files, tags etc.) created in the last 12 hours and filters them to show only commits.  Checking these is then a quick process.

I'd try the git-ressurect.sh script mentioned in [Jakub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653931/434243) first though.

Comment: Nice alternative idea! Your command throws an error though. The problem is with the "12h" part (actually the "h"). Once I removed the "h" it worked alright. From `man find`: "-ctime n - File's  status  was  last  changed  n*24  hours ago." So we should also change 12 to 0.5 to have the expected behaviour of last 12 hours.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.8 here, so the 'find' flags above are based on the version that it ships.

Comment: Yeah, sure the problem is with versions! That's why I upvoted your answer at first place! I just commented so people realize parameters might be different.

Answer (score 9):

**For [GitHub](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok) users without Git installed:**

If you want to restore it from [GitHub](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok) website, you can *use their API* to get a list of repo-related events:

**First**

- find those SHAs (commit hashes):

  `curl -i https://api.github.com/repos/PublicUser/PublicRepo/events`

  ... or for private repos:

  `curl -su YourUserName https://api.github.com/repos/YourUserName/YourProject/events`

  (will be prompted for GitHub password)

  - (If the repo rquires two-factor auth, see the comments on this answer below.)

**Next**

- go to [GitHub](https://github.com/Maxim-Mazurok) and create a new temporary branch which will be deleted for ever ([Chrome](https://www.google.com/chrome/) is preferable).

•  Go to branches and delete that one.

•  **On the same page, without reloading**, open DevTools, Network panel. Now prepare...

•  Click restore. You will notice a new "line". Right-click on it and select "Copy as cURL" and save this text in some editor.

•  Append to the end of the copied line of code, this one: `-H "Cookie="`.

You should now get something like:

```
    curl 'https://github.com/UserName/ProjectName/branches?branch=BranchSHA&name=BranchName' -H 'Cookie:' -H 'Origin: https://github.com' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US' -H 'User-Agent: User-Agent' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' -H 'Accept: */*' -H 'Referer: https://github.com/UserName/ProjectName/branches' -H 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=token' --compressed
```

**Final step**

- replace "BranchSHA" with your SHA-hash and BranchName with desired name (BTW, it is great hack to rename branch from web). If you were not too slow, you need to make this request anyhow. For example, just copy-paste to a terminal.

**P.S.**

I realize this may not be the "simplest solution" or the "right" solution, but it is offered in case someone finds it useful.

Comment: The above is one of the few out there that doesn't rely on `git reflog` and therefore was useful for example when having deleted a remote branch and lost access to the computer that was done from so nothing useful cold be obtained from `reflog`.

Note when [using OAuth or two-factor authentication on Github](https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#via-oauth-tokens) the `curl` command becomes of the form:
`curl -u username:token https://api.github.com/user` or
`curl -H "Authorization: token TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/USER_OR_ORG_NAME/REPO_NAME/events`

Comment: @TT-- wow, I'm glad it helped! and thanks for your contribution regarding auth token :)

Answer (score 8):

Make sure to perform all of this locally, and confirm your repo is in the state you desire before pushing to Bitbucket Cloud. It may also be a good idea to clone your current repo, and test these solutions out first.

1. If you just deleted the branch, you'll see something like this in your terminal:

```
    Deleted branch <your-branch> (was <sha>)
```

2.To restore the branch, use:

```
    git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

**If you don't know the 'sha' off the top of your head, you can:**

1. Find the 'sha' for the commit at the tip of your deleted branch using:

```
    git reflog
```

2. To restore the branch, use:

```
    git checkout -b <branch> <sha>
```

**If your commits are not in your reflog:**

1. You can try recovering a branch by reseting your branch to the sha of the commit found using a command like:

```
    git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt
```

2.You can then display each commit using one of these:

```
    git log -p <commit>
    git cat-file -p <commit>
```

Answer (score 7):

For recovering a deleted branch, First go through the reflog history,

```
git reflog -n 60
```

Where n refers to the last n commits. Then find the proper head and create a branch with that head.

```
git branch testbranch HEAD@{30}
```

Answer (score 4):

I rebased a branch from remote to try to clear a few commits I didn't want and was going to cherrypick the right ones that I wanted. Of course I wrote the SHAs wrong...

Here is how I found them (mostly an easier interface/interaction from things on answers here):

First, generate a list of loose commits in your log. Do this as soon as possible and stop working, as those may be dumped by the garbage collector.

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found > lost
```

This creates a `lost` file with all the commits you will have to look at. To simplify our life, let's cut only the SHA from it:

```
cat lost | cut -d\  -f3 > commits
```

Now you have a `commits` file with all the commits you have to look.

Assuming you are using Bash, the final step:

```
for c in `cat commits`; do  git show $c; read; done
```

This will show you the diff and commit information for each of them. And wait for you to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Now write down all the ones you want, and then cherry-pick them in. After you are done, just Ctrl-C it.

Answer (score 4):

A very common sub problem of the general problem of recovering deleted branches is recovering a feature branch after merging and then deleting it - as is common practice.

As this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005854/what-to-do-with-branch-after-merge) covers you can always recover a deleted branch if it has been merged successfully. This is because a branch is just a fancy pointer to a commit and because you've merged, the commit is still there. A merge commit will list the hash of the head commits of the two (or more) branches merged. For example:

```
        git show master
        commit 849675951d41497e7b07d34096ebf36dc713221 (HEAD -> master)
        Merge: fc1c9ce 97f8a60
        Author: Me
        Date:   Sun Jan 9 16:14:24 2022 +0100

            Merge branch 'feature'
```

So you can recover the delete 'feature' branch by doing `git checkout -b feature 97f8a60` - no need for any reflog stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I did this on the computer which i delete the branch:

`git reflog`

response:

```
74b2383 (develope) HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from master to develope
40ef328 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from develope to master
74b2383 (develope) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from master to develope
40ef328 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{4}: reset: moving to HEAD
40ef328 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{5}: clone: from http://LOCALGITSERVER/myBigProject/Android.git
```

and i retrieve the branch with this command:

`git checkout -b newBranchName 74b2383`

Answer (score 2):

**BIG YES**

*if you are using GIT*
follow these simple steps
**https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-765757540.html**

*if you are using smartgit and already push that branch*
**go to origin, find that branch and right click then checkout**

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using Git Extensions**

Although old, this thread is the top of the list when you google recovering deleted branches. I use git extensions rather than the command line and so am unfamiliar with the commands but the *reflog* command gave me a clue so I'm posting my git extensions solution here for others that are using git extensions who may read this.

1. Go to the *view* dropdown on the tool bar
2. Select *Show reflog references*

Your deleted branch should now be viewable and selectable, simply click on it and check it out.

Answer (score 0):

First go to git batch the move to your project like :

```
cd android studio project
cd Myproject
then type :
git reflog
```

You all have a list of the changes and the reference number take the ref number then checkout 
from android studio or from the git betcha.
another solution take the ref number and go to android studio click on git branches down then click on checkout tag or revision past the reference number then lol you have the branches.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to tfe's answer, you can recover with this process mentioned, unless it's commits are not garbage collected. Git branch is simply a pointer to a particular commit in the commit tree. But if you delete the pointer, and the commits on that branch are not merged into other existing branch, then git treats it as dangling commits and removes them during garbage collection, which it may run automatically periodically.

If your branch wasn't merged to an existing branch, and if it was garbage collected, then you will loose all commits up until the point from where branch was forked from an existing branch.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `git reflog` did not return the `sha` for me. 
Only the `commit id` (which is 8 chars long and a sha is way longer)

So I used
`git reflog --no-abbrev`

And then do the same as mentioned above:
`git checkout -b <branch> <sha>`

Comment: you can always use the abbreviated 8 character sha, you don't have to use the full sha

Answer (score 0):

#### IF you are using VSCode... *and* you synced your branch with the server at some point before deleting it...

Note that git branch delete only deletes the local copy, not the copy on the server. First, in the Git panel (git icon on left toolbar), look through the branches and see if your branch is still there under "origin/your_branch_name". If so, just select that and you should get your code back (suggest that you immediately copy/paste/save it locally somewhere else).

If you didn't see an "origin/your_branch_name", Install the GitLens extension.  This allows you to visually poke around in the server repositories and locate the copy you synced to the server. If you have multiple repositories, note that it might be necessary to have at least one file opened from the desired repository in order to make the repository appear in GitLens. Then:

1. Open the GitLens panel
2. Expand the repository
3. You should see a list of categories: Branches / Contributors / Remotes / Stashes / etc

You should find YourLostTreasure under "Branches" or possibly under "Remotes -> Origins". Hopefully, you will see a branch with the desired name - if you expand it, you should see the files you changed in that branch. Double-click the file names to open them, and immediately back up that code.

If you don't immediately see your lost branch, poke around and if you find something promising, immediately open it and grab the code. I had to poke around quite a bit until I found TheGoldenBranch, and even then the code was missing the last one or two saves (possibly because I failed to sync to server before attempting-a-Branch-Merge-but-accidentally-clicking-Branch-Delete). My search was unnecessarily lengthened because when I first found the branch I wasn't completely sure the name was correct so kept looking, and it took some time to re-find that first branch. *(Thus, Carpe Carpum and* ***then*** *keep looking.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you already push branch to remote server then try to use `git checkout <branch>` and git will try to clone from you're last origin mirror in your local machine.