# git: find the last commit hash for a deleted branch 4-5 months ago

Tags: git

4-5 months ago, I deleted one of the remote/local branches (named as "dev0001"). Now, I need to access that branch. Therefore, **I need to find the latest commit hash** inside that deleted branch so that I can recover it.

Do you know how to find the latest commit hash of a deleted branch and then checkout it to my local computer?

I found lots of questions and answers on Stackoverflow regarding recording a branch but don't know how to find latest commit hash of a deleted branch 4-5 months ago.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might want to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543280/how-do-i-get-the-deleted-branch-back-in-git or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543280/how-do-i-get-the-deleted-branch-back-in-git

Comment: Thanks Olaf, but git log doesn't list commits made on a deleted branch :(

Comment: these questions deal with deleted branch, why don't they fit to your problem?

Comment: Yes, they deal with the deleted branch but deleted branches which have been merged to master branch. In my case, the dev0001 branch has never been merged to master or any other existing branch :( I guess I can find a hash via git fsck. If I can find the solution, I will post it here.

Comment: Have you already searched for `git reflog | grep 'moving.*dev0001'`?

Comment: You might also try `git fsck`. Options `--unreachable` and `--lost-found` might be interesting, too.

Comment: Olaf, thanks for comments. git fsck returned me unreachable commits. I achieved to checkout a branch commit (I found the commit hash from fsck) but some files are missing, unable to retrieve them. Any comments?

Answer (score 0):

If you can [view the **reflog**](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) for that branch, it will list the commits - you can try:

```
git reflog show dev0001
```

Alternatively, you can search the reflog for `HEAD`:

```
git reflog
```

... for mentions of `dev0001`.

However, since the default time for reflog entries to expire is 90 days, that may not produce any results.

Are you sure that any remote-tracking branches for `dev0001` have also been deleted?  To check that, I would try:

```
git branch -a | grep dev0001
```

... in every repository that might have fetched that branch at some point.  It's common for people to have remote-tracking branches left over even after they've been deleted on the server they originally fetched it from.