# Error: You have exceeded your disk space quota error message in git

Tags: git, branch, diskspace

When I try to push to my repositoty I see the following error message:

```
Error: You have exceeded your disk space quota.
Please upgrade your account or remove some data.

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
```

To create more space, I am trying to delete a remote branch that is no longer needed. 
But it wont let me push to delete the remote branch.

Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: ... ask whoever maintains your remote server to increase your quota?

Comment: I was hoping I can cleanup some redundant stuff and create more space. I will ask them too. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was hoping I can cleanup some redundant stuff and create more space

You couldn't reduce significantly the size of an [upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2749166/6309) repo from a downstream location.
That upstream repo is likely a bare repo, and even deleting a branch wouldn't change much (a branch is just a pointer, and the [reflog of that repo would still have the reference of the commits for that branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543479/6309).

All the commands mentioned in "[Reduce git repository size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2116778/6309)" are *local* commands.

So even without increasing the disk space, you would still need an admin to go on that server an clean that repo for you.