# Restore deleted git branch from Phabricator revision

Tags: git, phabricator, arcanist

I have an opened phabricator revision and I have accidentally deleted the underlying git branch.
I can retrieve the diffs from the revision and re-create the branch.

But, Is there a way howto restore the deleted branch from the revision?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `arc patch` to create a branch.  It will create a branch called `arcpatch-D###` where D### is your Diff ID.  Once you have that branch, you can use git commands to create a new branch based from the head of that branch and name it however you like.

Recommended steps:
1. `arc patch D###`
2. `git checkout -b new-branch-name`

From there you can do anything else you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the underlying git repo, you can simply use [`git reflog`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog): you will see the commit referenced by the deleted branch.

See for example "[How do I get the deleted-branch back in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543479/6309)".

Comment: Unfortunately, I have deleted the whole underlying git repo as well.