# What to do with branch after merge

Tags: git, merge, branch

I had two branches: `master` and `branch1`. I just merged `branch1` back into `master` and I'm done with that branch. Should I delete it or just let it sit around? Will deleting it cause any loss of data?

Comment: See also: [How to use git merge --squash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5308816/562769)

Answer (score 553, accepted):

After the merge, it's safe to delete the branch:

```
git branch -d branch1
```

Additionally, git will warn you (and refuse to delete the branch) if it thinks you didn't fully merge it yet. If you forcefully delete a branch (with `git branch -D`) which is not completely merged yet, you have to do some tricks to get the unmerged commits back though (see below).

There are some reasons to keep a branch around though. For example, if it's a feature branch, you may want to be able to do bugfixes on that feature still inside that branch.

If you also want to delete the branch on a remote host, you can do:

```
git push origin :branch1
```

Or its equivalent:

```
git push -d origin branch1
```

This will forcefully delete the branch on the remote (this will not affect already checked-out repositiories though and won't prevent anyone with push access to re-push/create it).

---

`git reflog` shows the recently checked out revisions. Any branch you've had checked out in the recent repository history will also show up there. Aside from that, `git fsck` will be the tool of choice at any case of commit-loss in git.

Comment: If you want to save the branch you can create a tag before deleting it. The if you want to go back to that point you can checkout that tag.

Comment: @Joqus I’d rather suggest to keep it as a branch in that case. Just don’t publish it.

Comment: Just in case - if you want to "completely merge" the branch before deleting it, just push that branch after merging, but before deleting. Something like `git checkout master && git merge branch1 && git push origin branch1 && git branch -d branch1`

Comment: What about the history of the branch you deleted? How is it safe to delete the branch with this in mind?

Answer (score 30):

I prefer **RENAME** rather than **DELETE**

All my branches are named in the form of

- `Fix/fix-<somedescription>` or
- `Ftr/ftr-<somedescription>` or
- etc.

Using Tower as my git front end, it neatly organizes all the `Ftr/`, `Fix/`, `Test/` etc. into folders.
Once I am done with a branch, I **rename** them to `Done/...-<description>`.

That way they are still there (which can be handy to provide history) and I can always go back knowing what it was (feature, fix, test, etc.)

Comment: Do you also rename the remote branches?

Comment: It seems redundant to _keep_ these branches, and insane to *rename* them. Am I missing something here? You can always recreate the branch. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Comment: makes no sense to keep branches after they were merged

Comment: +1 for the Idea on renaming to Fix, Test and Done... Keeping branches is how contractors get paid on my company.

Comment: @ksav if you do, will it have the history that it previously had before merge then deletion?

Comment: @ksav not always. Git reflog will clean entries older than 90 days.

Answer (score 7):

If you DELETE the branch after merging it, just be aware that all hyperlinks, URLs, and references of your DELETED branch will be **BROKEN**.