# Why do we delete branch after merge in git?

Tags: git, branch

I have experience with Mercurial in which we close branch after merge. However, we don't delete the source branch so that if an issue is found, we can track all the merges in the `master` branch to identify grossly (the branch) where the issue comes from. Then we track the commits of the branch to identify the culprit.

In git, I read that [we should delete branch after merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14005854/what-to-do-with-branch-after-merge). My questions are

1. Why? If a bug is found, how can we identify the bugged commit which has been merged to `master`?
2. In general, how do you git guys track the history to identify the commit that bugs?

Comment: You can grep commit messages and find the merge commit of interest. Moreover, Git provides a `bisect` subcommand to home in on a commit that introduced a bug.

Comment: I don't see how preserving branches helps to identify issues. Anyway, as @Jubobs mentionned, git provide the super powerful subcommand `bisect`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2613954/2303202 tldr: deleting branch does not delete commits if it was merged

Comment: BTW, as in mercurial "branch" is just a string property of commits, it is literally impossible to delete a branch without modifying the history. "Closing" a branch is adding a most recent "closing" commit, so that the branch is not shown in list of active branches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to add a bit to [kostix's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896850/1256452): In Mercurial, commits are *permanently affixed to*, and hence contained within, *exactly one branch*.  The branch that contains a commit is the branch that was current when the commit was made.

This means that a diagram that looks like this is sensible:

```
branch1:  C1 <-C2 <-C3 <-M
                        /
branch2:    C4 <-C5 <-C6
```

since the commits will always be on those branches.

This is not true in Git: as noted, each Git commit is on *zero or more* branches, and the set changes dynamically over time.  We should put the branch names on the *right* and have arrows coming out of them, pointing to commits, rather than putting the name on the left and letting it flow rightward "against" the backwards-pointing arrows:

```
C1 <-C2 <-C3 <-M   <-- branch1
              /
  C4 <-C5 <-C6   <-- branch2
```

This lets us move the names around, even to other rows of the diagram, without worrying about which commits are to their right.  The flow is entirely right-to-left, not mixed.

Comment: Thanks, I upvote. Do you have a simple case in which the Git approach is better than the Mercurial one?

Comment: I wrote about this in my (unfinished) book. The Mercurial method is much clearer to newbies and much simpler to explain, but ultimately it causes problems over the long term. See the last paragraph currently on pages 42-43 [here](http://web.torek.net/torek/tmp/book.pdf).

Comment: @torek I was unaware (until now) that you were writing a book! Any ETA?

Comment: @Jubobs: the project is quite stalled now that I have a full time job again (alas!). On some weekends I get a little bit of work done now and then.

Comment: @torek Best of luck, both with the book and the new job!

Answer (score 7):

First, compared to Mercurial's branches, Git branches are "anonymous".

This means, a commit which was recorded "on a" branch (most of them are,
but this is not required) bears *no information* about the branch it was
committed to.
This is intentional.
In this model, a branch is merely "a pointer" to some commit which—through
the parent/child(ren) relations—can be used to traverse the history of changes backwards.

The consequence is that any commit recorded in a repository may be
*reachable* via any number of branches (and tags).
So, in this model, any commit may "be on" any number of branches at the same time.

Second, a merge commit not only records the name of the branch being
merged (this is merely the default behaviour; it's perfectly legal to
merge a chain of history by naming its tip commit or override/edit
the merge message) but actually the tip commit of that branch at the time
of the merge. So this information is recorded in the merge commit itself,
and that line of history is permanently there: say, if you have merged
branch B into branch A resulting in a merge commit M, you can refer to
the tip of that branch B at the time of the merge via `M^2` which means
"the second parent of `M`" (the first parent is the tip of A at the time
of the merge).

Given that Git branches are lightweight, should you need to
"get back in time" to "work on" B at the time of the merge,
you can just do

```
$ git checkout -b oldB M^2
```

which is "create a new branch named «oldB» pointing at the 2nd parent
of the merge commit «M» and check it out".

After you're done with exploring the old state of B, just get rid of that
"oldB" branch.

---

To round up, Git is best approached from another angle: think in term
of the graph of interconnected commits with branches merely pointing
to certain "entry points" to that graph.

Comment: See `git help revisions` for more info on that `M^<n>` notation.