# Recover deleted branch in Git

Tags: git, git-branch

I have deleted my branch by mistake like this:

```
git branch -D demo
```

But I want to recover it… I get this after `git reflog`

```
541b2f5 HEAD@{23}: checkout: moving from demo to master
06fa6d5 HEAD@{24}: commit (merge): remove ajax call for deleting variables and transfomers
b84b60a HEAD@{25}: checkout: moving from demo1 to demo
```

I want to create branch with sha `06fa6d5`… so I tried this:

```
git checkout -b demo  06fa6d5

git checkout -b demo  HEAD@{24}
```

But I didn't get code from that…

Comment: your commands are correct and should work. Your question lacks details.

Comment: Looks like this was resolved. I really liked this answer for this situation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Create a list of all dangling or unreachable commits.

```
git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found
```

Print a list of commit messages for all commits in the lost and found.

```
ls -1 .git/lost-found/commit/ | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline
```

Find your missing commit through the process of manual inspection (i.e. reading).
Create a new branch with the missing commit as the branch head.

```
git checkout -b branch-name SHA
```

Comment: that was amazing. I did this on windows using mysisgit. had to change the process a little bit because the the lost and found directory was not in any sensible place. I took the output of `git fsck...` and checked the SHA for every `commmit` (not blob or tree) by doing a `git log SHA`

Comment: I have also been to adapt it:

    `git fsck --full --no-reflogs --unreachable --lost-found | grep commit | cut -d\  -f3 | xargs -n 1 git log -n 1 --pretty=oneline > .git/lost-found.txt`

Comment: Philippe's oneline command worked for me in git bash for windows. I just had to add an extra space after -d\ in " cut -d\ -f3 " (cannot show it in comments as the formatting removes duplicate spaces)

Comment: Nice one @Phillipe! 

Answer (score 1):

Having got the potential sha1 for the last tip of branch `demo`, use `gitk sha1` to actually browse the commit's history to check you have the right one.