# I deleted a branch without merging into master

Tags: git

I was trying to make a current branch the master and keep masters history by following this:

```
git checkout better_branch
git merge --strategy=ours master    # keep the content of this branch, but record a merge
git checkout master
git merge better_branch
```

but somewhere along the line I messed up and before checking I deleted the better branch (moronic I know). Now I have the commit number of the branch I deleted in the state I wanted it but i dont know if/how I can bring it back. I did a git reset --hard 7585773 but it only reset master(i think). Is there anyway to get my branch back or make master have that branches changes or have I lost them?

this is my git log

```
commit 758577310015683cd2de688afe0aeb0638eef507
Author: Regan <xxxxxx@gmail.com>
Date:   Tue Mar 3 11:10:19 2015 -0800

    add angular files, setup config file, add backstrech
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I recover branch after its deletion in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Comment: if this is a duplicate question, and the linked answer worked should I delete my question?

Comment: Not necessarily. The different way of formulating the question might helps others to eventually find the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that if you consult with this StackOverflow post [Recover deleted branch git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16793637/recover-deleted-branch-git) then you will be able to recover your branch, or possibly this post because the other is marked as a duplicate: [Can I recover branch after its deletion in git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

> Yes, you should be able to do `git reflog` and find the SHA1 for the
>   commit at the tip of your deleted branch, then just `git checkout [sha]`. And once you're at that commit, you can just `git checkout -b [branchname]` to make a recreate the branch from there.

Using this command: `git checkout -b <branch> <sha>`

Comment: YAY! thanks this worked! I will mark this as right as soon as I can