# NetBeans: Git: Switching to different branch, commit lost

Tags: php, git, netbeans

I'm using NetBeans 7.4 and local GIT repository. When I tried to check in my last changes I've got the message saying that HEAD is detached in repository, do I want to check in. I've chose Yes.
After that, I switched back to my main branch,  but I couldn't find my last check in there. Anonymous branch that appeared before, disappeared. I am not able to find my last check in. Is there any way to find it?

Comment: Git support in Netbeans is good, but a bit weird and confusing, especially if you use Git ocasionally as opposed to daily usage. I recommend command-line usage for most operations (commits, pulls, pushes, switching branches etc).

Answer (score 0):

You can force that last commit back in command line,  using [git reflog](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

You will be able to find the SHA1 of that commit you did before switching back to your main branch, and you [can make a branch on top of that SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640806/6309).