# What happens to commits left behind from git branch -D

Tags: git, git-branch

I worked on an experimental branch and now want to delete it. Running `git branch -d experimental` outputs

```
error: The branch 'experimental' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D experimental'.
```

After running deleting the branch with -D, what happens to the commits left behind?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I recover branch after the deletion in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-the-deletion-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They stay where they are in the git graph, simply there's no explicit reference to them anymore.

If you have the hash of a specific commit in that branch you can still refer to it, try for instance

```
git log <commit-sha>
```

where `<commit-sha>` is the hash of the commit.

That being said, also note that those "dangling" commits may disappear in the future when someone runs `git prune` (directly or via `git gc`, which in modern versions of git is run automatically when needed), which deletes all the unreachable objects from the graph.