# Recover a Git branch that was deleted months ago

Tags: git, branch, restore

I deleted a branch months ago thinking that it was no longer required in my project.  It turns out that now, months later, it's actually required again.  I don't have it locally unfortunately...

Is there a way I can restore it?

EDIT:  I have cloned the repo after deleting the branch, so I believe the reflog can't help me.

I have also tried the "Resurrect" http://repo.or.cz/w/git.git/blob/HEAD:/contrib/git-resurrect.sh  which isn't showing me the branch.

EDIT #2 :  Those are all good answers but I think I'm screwed.  The reflog is of no help to me any more since I've re-cloned, it was a branch sitting out all by itself, it's not on the remote server and nobody else has it locally.

I think I'll just rewrite it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I recover branch after its deletion in git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the branch if one of below options occur:

(Specify if any and ill update the answer accordingly)

- If you have merged the branch to some other branch
- You have it stored locally on your repo (which mean that no gc was running during this time)
- You have it on the remote server
- Someone else has it in his repo
- You have a clue which file you are looking for and this will allow me to explain how to search the git blobs looking for it)

Mean while take a look here for more ideas:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revert-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can recover a deleted branch in git.

First, run `git reflog` and find the **SHA1 for the commit at the tip of your deleted branch**.

Then just `git checkout -b <branchname> <sha>` to recreate the branch and its history.

Comment: 90 days could do a trick here. I would recommend add grep and name of branch to example.

Comment: Reflog will not help once the gc was executed or if he cloned the repo again. the default value for GC to run is usually 90 days.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try `git reflog`and find the latest commit hash for the branch that you have deleted ? 
Once you have the commit hash, perform `git reset --hard <commit>`.
This will revert the HEAD back to the latest commit on the branch. 
Recreate the branch again and checkout to that new branch `git checkout -b <branchname>`
Then push the branch, `git push origin <branchname>`

I found this on the Atlassian Knowledge Base at https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/how-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-744723130.html

I hope this helps