# How do I recover deleted branches after git clone?

Tags: git, github

I have a local git repository (which was cloned from a remote `origin` branch):

```
~/foo
```

I had some branches in the local repository:

```
~/foo$ git branch
*master
branch1
branch2
```

The `origin` repository has a branch `branch3` that my local does not have, and I wanted to add it to my local. I did the following, hoping `branch3` will be added to my local repository:

```
~/foo/..$ git clone -b branch3 --single-branch git@github.com:<localrespository_name>.git
```

After that, I see that there is only `branch3` in the local respository:

```
~/foo$ git branch
*branch3
```

Where are my `branch1`, `branch2`, and how can I recover them?

I don't have copies of `branch1`, `branch2` in the remote repository.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git) question may help you. If it doesn't (e.g. `.git` directory was already cleaned), I doubt you can do something.

Comment: The linked answers didn't help me, but I found a way to recover. Even though I could not find a way to see my previous branches on the local, I was somehow able to push them to a remote repository of mine: `git push git@myremote_repository.git branch1`, and the same for `branch2`.

Comment: Next time, just do `git checkout branch3`. Git will automatically set up the remote tracking for you.

Answer (score 0):

If a remote branch3 already existed, it should have been enough to do a

`git checkout -b branch3 origin/branch3`

instead of the clone command you used.

You may see all branches (including remotes) with

```
git branch --all
```

in example, on a linux-stable tree:

```
andi@SHARK:~/working_git/linux-stable$ git branch
  master
andi@SHARK:~/working_git/linux-stable$ git branch --all
* master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/linux-2.6.11.y
  remotes/origin/linux-2.6.12.y
  remotes/origin/linux-2.6.13.y
  remotes/origin/linux-2.6.14.y
  <SNIP>
  remotes/origin/linux-4.9.y
  remotes/origin/master
  andi@SHARK:~/working_git/linux-stable$ git checkout -b v4.9 origin/linux-4.9.y
  Checking out files: 100% (11425/11425), done.
  Branch v4.9 set up to track remote branch linux-4.9.y from origin.
  Switched to a new branch 'v4.9'
  andi@SHARK:~/working_git/linux-stable$ git branch
     master
   * v4.9
  andi@SHARK:~/working_git/linux-stable$ git log -1
  commit 75353ac8ff437322ca5520b28d9f9b4b41b39bd6
  Author: Greg Kroah-Hartman <gregkh@linuxfoundation.org>
  Date:   Sun Jan 15 13:43:07 2017 +0100

      Linux 4.9.4
```

Now we got the local v4.9 branch on the remote/origin/linux-v4.9.y branch.