# Recovering a deleted git branch

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project. Now a few weeks later the client asked me about a branch I had called **feature/zomato**

It's gone, It can't checkout to it anymore, I don't see it my list of branches in phpstorm either.

I looked online for some solutions

#### Reflog Solution

This solution required you to know that latest commit on that branch, but the only rows I see in reflog are switching to and away to that branch, I don't see any commits being made on it.

[image]

#### Do you know other solutions to restore a deleted branch? **Or the proof that I deleted it? Is it possible to see that in logs somewhere?

Thank you!

Comment: try `git branch` it will print all available the branch

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Comment: It's not there when I try "git branch".

Comment: As I typed above here, That didn't work because I can't see what the latest sha is on that branch.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I recover a branch after its deletion in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Comment: Nope! As I said before I don't know the latest sha, did you even read my full question? I know how to search on stackoverflow.

Comment: The hash at the left of the `git reflog` output *is* the hash to which the branch pointed at the time you ran `git checkout`. Unless something else moved the branch since then (which *is* possible, e.g., you could have run `branch -f <name> <newhash>`), that would be the latest hash on that branch.

Comment: Did you even read the answer at Channaveer's link? The SHAs are in the reflog output. You can recreate the branch from the SHA, with complete history, because that's [how commit objects work](https://blog.thoughtram.io/git/2014/11/18/the-anatomy-of-a-git-commit.html).

Comment: I tried all those steps, I'm nog getting my branch back, nothing changes compared to the master branch. Thanks for your response.

Comment: In your current repo, the `develop` and `feature/zomato` branches are pointing to the same commit: `5945f47`. The reflog history expires [after 90 days (by default)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog#git-reflog---expirelttimegt). Is it possible that more than 90 days ago, you did a hard reset to make zomato point to develop?

Comment: Also, reflog only tracks the current repo. It's not shared with other repos. Is it possible you were working on another machine at the time? If so, reflog is not going to help unless you can get back to that machine/repo.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'm sure I was on this machine. Might be duplicate of a codebase with different repo, I'll check that out now. And it might be around 3 months ago so 90 days could be true...

Answer (score 0):

If you've deleted (or moved) the ref but haven't GC'd it, you can use `git fsck --lost-found` to get a list of dangling commits. If one (or more) show up, you can then recreate the branch from the SHA (`git branch feature/zomato SHA`).