# lost my QT5 .ui file, recovery from pyuic5 .py output

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

Is there any way to generate the original .ui file from the qtuic5 .py output? I removed & deleted a branch and later realized it removed the .ui file.

Comment: Are you using git? It might be possible to [recover the deleted branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3640764/190597). (A similar method might be available for other version control systems too.)

Comment: @unutbu Just combed through and its not comitted. I don't know what happened but all the temporary files seem to have been cleared mid development. Is there any recovery tools at all?

Comment: If you have a transcript of the git commands you've entered, a git expert (probably not me) might be able to help you recover the file. To the best of my knowledge, the changes have to have been either [staged](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/119782/13014), [stashed](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing), or committed to be recoverable.

Comment: Followed the duplicate and its for a dialog window instead of a MainWindow. Reconstruction did not work, maybe 10% recovery.