# how to recover deleted branch after deletion from Pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm, branch

Have deleted the branch from Pycharm . I got a suboption as delete and accidentally I clicked it. The branch got deleted from the origin .Is there a way to recover the branch other than using git?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I recover a branch after its deletion in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+recover+deleted+branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Don't run: git gc**

Run below commands in terminal at root of project.

Find all dangling commits:

```
git fsck --no-reflog
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
Checking objects: 100% (8459/8459), done.
dangling commit 2e04e4159219dbd35f55a53fb0c6ae9c187f6b8e
dangling commit 9db660c967e3b410b354c0024090a5d0bfabb614
dangling commit dc6f48a17b749ad6a76ec1fe9434b8427487dbb6
```

Checkout to commit to see if it was your last commit.

```
git checkout 2e04e4159219dbd35f55a53fb0c6ae9c187f6b8e
git log
```

If found commit is right commit, then checkout your branch from it

```
git checkout -b <YOUR BRANCH>
```

Your branch is recovered.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any way to recover the branch through pycharm ?

Comment: I am not aware of pycharm interface, but you can recover your branch once you go in bash. :)

Answer (score 6):

In PyCharm you can find the hash of deleted branch in logs (Help > Show Log in Files).

Then run

```
git checkout -b <branch_name> <found_hash>
```

Comment: Should be (Help > Show Log in Finder)

Comment: this is simpler and worked for me, you saved me =) thanks

Comment: Nice and clean [and hacky!]

Answer (score 1):

there is a notification button on the top-right of the Pycharm or any jetbrains IDEs if you press it and you see your recent activities like deleting a branch now click on restore to recover your deleted branch
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To restore a local branch that was deleted:

In PyCharm 2019.3.4, you can:

1. create a new branch
2. show the version control tool window (View -> Tool Windows -> Version Control)
3. click on the Log tab
4. search for branch by name (or scroll back through history - what ever works)
5. right-click on branch, select "Reset Current Branch to Here..."
6. select appropriate reset mode: soft, mixed, hard, keep and click Reset
7. reconcile changes with base branch

Tips:

- Always work in a disposable branch until you are happy with results.
- If in a disposable branch, you can easily try the different reset modes to find the one that best suits your situation.

Notes:

- I like the PyCharm Version Control Log viewer because it pulls together all the metadata in a historical tree view. I can locate the branch through name, tag, commit comments, browsing the changes that were made.