# Git recover local files deleted by git fetch origin + git reset --hard

Tags: git

I'm pretty new with GIT and i accidentally (not really) deleted a bunch of local files while trying to recover changes from the repository, i have a frontend branch where i work and i make the following in order to bring back some changes:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/frontend
```

Is there any way to recover the files that I lost because of this? I know there's a lot of threads about recovering files out there but since I'm a newbie I really want to have feedback on this specific case. Any help will be REALLY appreciated.

**Important Update**: Before doing all of this I commit all my changes (that included the files that I lost) to the repository, that's why I thought that I will get the same thing when I did the fetch origin, I have tried to list my commits but I'm not seeing this last commit.

Comment: Did you push your commit to remote before losing them?

Comment: Check your reflog (`git reflog`), your commit should be there.

Comment: @MohamedAneesA thanks for your reply. As far as I remember yes I did push my commit, is there any way to recover those lost files if I haven't?

Comment: Then you can go to github and view your latest commits. Get the commit hash and use *git reset head -- hard <your commit hash>*

Comment: @RomainValeri thanks a lot i actually see my commit with an id of d77424b.

Comment: @MohamedAneesA, It Worked !! , thanks a lot guys you saved the day

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I recover a branch after its deletion in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just posting this in order to answer my question (already answered by @RomainValeri and @MohammedAneesA in the comments).

I was able to solve this by getting all my commits with "git reflog"
I got my last commit hash and then did a "reset head -- hard "

That solved it.