# Recover deleted git branch with -D

Tags: git

I accidentally deleted git branch using:

```
  "git delete -D branchName"
```

is it possible to recover this branch?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Comment: @Stuart The question asked in the post is about "git delete -d" which is local delete, whereas I have mistakenly done "git delete -D" which is remote delete

Comment: @JannatArora No, this is a misunderstanding. `-D` has nothing to do with remote deletion, it's an entirely local operation. The difference between `-d` and `-D` is the check for unmerged commits in the branch, which is overridden in the latter case.

Answer (score 0):

Use `git reflog` to get the SHA of the deleted branch and the git checkout to restore it.

full explanation can be found here:
[How to move HEAD back to a previous location? (Detached head) & Undo commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head-undo-commits/34519716#34519716)

Comment: I did a "git delete -D" which is remote delete. I know the SHA of deleted branch..will this work in my case too

Comment: `git delete -D` has nothing to do with remote deletion. It is just a shortcut for `--delete --force`. `-d` allows you to delete only fully merged branches, while with `-D` you can delete whatever branch you want.