# Data is gone after git branch

Tags: git

I had a remote branch called `bug_fix` that I wanted to rename to `status_page`. These are steps that I have taken being on `master`:

```
git branch bug_fix // this was a mistake
git branch -m bug_fix status_page
git push origin --delete bug_fix
git push origin status_page
```

After `git branch bug_fix` the code was same as in master and basically I pushed empty branch. Is there a way to get back the code from `bug_fix`?

Comment: you can try to reset changes to last commit

Comment: @MatzHeri commits are gone as well :(

Comment: please check this question might it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Comment: @MatzHeri thanks for advice, this would work, but `git reflog` does not show old commits at all, probably because the repository was newly cloned

Comment: I was hoping to offer a solution using `git fsck --unreachable --no-reflogs` but in trying to verify it I wasn't able to show it working for your use case. You may give that a shot and look at commits there to find the correct one. Also, do you have collaborators you can leverage? If they have a recent checkout they will have the commit hash in question and can recover the branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was managed to recover lost branch following instructions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22303923/10817859).

P.S.: Thanks @MatzHeri and @PhiloEpisteme for help :)