# I have deleted the master branch of a project by mistake

Tags: git, github

I have deleted the remote master branch by mistake and now I don't  have local code and i am getting out of my mind because all the team code was in that branch.
Please help me i am stuck very bad.

Comment: What exactly did you do to delete the master branch?

Comment: Step 1: Don't Panic, the code is almost certainly recoverable. Step 2: Click [edit] and explain exactly what you did, and someone can tell you the easiest way to recover from it. Step 3: Set up [branch protection](https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches) in Github so that this doesn't happen again.

Comment: If anyone on your team has a sandbox cloned, including yourself, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/3640806/3216427 to recreate the remote branch from your local (possibly deleted) one.

Comment: Does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I think the only thing you can do is to ask around your teammates, if someone has the local branch. From there, you can restore /  push it to wherever your remote branch was originally.