# how do i go back to my previous commit after git stash?

Tags: git

I did a git commit, but I just remembered that I checked out the wrong branch, I did a git stash and deleted branch

```
git checkout -b "myBranch"
git add .
git commit -m "message"
git stash
git branch -d "myBranch"
```

this is not stored, how do I restore my stash to the new branch?

```
git checkout -b "myBranch" dev
git stash pop
```

Comment: Nothing that was committed by `git commit -m "message"` would have been stashed. Use `git reflog` to recover and rebase your commit. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is lost, it's just not where you think it is.

1. check your reflog (`git reflog`) to find back the commit you created in your first command (when `myBranch` started at the wrong point)
2. from your current (correct) `myBranch`, run :

```
git cherry-pick <sha of the reflog commit>
```

(for step 1: if you were still in the same terminal as the one where you created the "wrong" commit, you could also use the sha printed on your console when you ran `git commit -m "message"`)