# Accidentally deleted all the past commits

Tags: git, github, git-commit, git-push

I was force pushing something onto my github repository. This was the first time I was using force in a command. After the push, all of my previous commits had been removed from github. I don't know if that's the default behaviour or if I did something wrong but is there any way to restore my previous commits? I don't mind removing the forced commit if that helps.

git push -f --set-upstream origin main
This is the command that I was using to push but it removed all of my previous commits.

Comment: Do you still see the old commits in `git reflog`?

Comment: Some quick advice. Double-check `git log` for the lost commits locally. Use `git reflog` and make a note the lost commit hash. Then you can make a branch pointing to that commit `git checkout -b recovery <commit-hash>`, this will at least prevent the commits being deleted.

Comment: You will find answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3640764/717372

Comment: No I don't see the old commits in  git reflog