# How do I recover a branch which I deleted both the local and the GitHub version of it and changed the default branch?

Tags: git, github, git-branch

Okay so I somehow mixed up my branches while trying to fix them, and ended up deleting the one I wanted both locally and in GitHub.

It all started when I was taught that I could use git.ignore to get DS_Store to stop showing up and rending my branches unusable.

So after I implemented that, I made a new branch. Then I set this new branch as my new default, since the my original default branch was broken DS_Store, and then I deleted all the other branches and their remotes on GitHub (except an older one which I had a new feature on); however, when I booted the app up I promptly realized that my code was a week behind of non stop bug fixing and optimizing.

I'm still a beginner super new to using terminals, but I've been looking at questions in stack exchange. I either can't find one that matches my specific question or it does not work.

**Things that haven't worked:**
Since I deleted the branches on GitHub I can't just clone them from a repository I believe.
I can't find the term "deleted branch" on the terminal.
When I type in "git log" - I don't see the commit I want to go back to.

**Things with promise :**
When I type in "git reflog" I am able to find what I think would be the commit I want to go back to :
"1ae4160 HEAD@{21}: commit: Fixed zombie targeting."

But when I type :

"git branch  1ae4160"

I get :

"zsh: no such file or directory: newDebug"

Comment: Recovering a deleted branch can be tricky, but `git reflog` is a good start. Instead of `git branch 1ae4160`, try `git checkout -b newBranchName 1ae4160`. Remember, `git reflog` is local to your machine, so it only helps if the commits were once present in your local repo

Comment: @evolutionxbox That should work but I would use `git switch -c newBranchName 1ae4160` (or `git switch -d 1ae4160` if you don't want to create a new branch). `git checkout` was replaced by newer, less confusing commands and it should not be used anymore.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I recover a branch after its deletion in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3640764/can-i-recover-a-branch-after-its-deletion-in-git)

Comment: @PiotrSiupa That does not answers my question. As I mentioned `"I can't find the term "deleted branch" on the terminal"` and the answer of that question involves `"If you've just deleted the branch you'll see something like this in your terminal Deleted branch <your-branch> (was <sha>)"`

Comment: @classyname That answer also mentions how to get the hash if you don't have this message and beside that you already have the hash so you can skip this part.

Comment: @PiotrSiupa, i don't think `git checkout` should not be used anymore - it is matter of preference now, to use it or `git switch` and `git restore` commands. Personally, i prefer to know very well one complex command, instead of knowing bad 3 different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to restore a deleted branch and reset to a specific commit. Let's go step by step.

Firstly, to recreate the branch at the commit "1ae4160," you can use the following commands:

```
# Create a new branch at the desired commit
git branch newDebug 1ae4160

# Switch to the new branch
git checkout newDebug
```

Or, you can combine these into a single command:

```
git checkout -b newDebug 1ae4160
```

However, it looks like you're encountering an issue with the Zsh shell. Make sure you are in the correct directory of your Git repository before running these commands.

If you're still facing issues, you can try using the full commit hash or a unique prefix of the commit hash:

```
git checkout -b newDebug 1ae4160
```

Replace 1ae4160 with the full commit hash or a unique prefix.

Additionally, if you've deleted the branch on GitHub, you might not see it when you clone the repository. However, if the branch is present in the local repository, you can push it back to GitHub:

```
git push origin newDebug
```

This assumes that you've recreated the branch locally as described above.

I hope this helps! If you encounter any specific errors or have additional details, please provide them for more targeted assistance.