# Not currently on any branch + git commit + checkout when not in any branch. Did I lose my changes?

Tags: git, commit

I was not currently on any branch when I commited my changes.
I didn't really notice the message and checked out another branch.

How can I retrieve my changes?
I can't merge or checkout, since there is no branch to merge from.

Comment: do you still have the console output from when you committed? did it contain the SHA1 of the commit? If so, you have the commit object, which is all you need

Comment: I... didn't know you could ever *not* be in a branch...

Comment: @Ignacio most common case of not being on a branch is when you checkout a commit that it's not of the tip of a branch

Comment: @Ignacio: and it's very useful!  You can jump about between commits in your history without moving any branch tip - particularly useful, for example, when trying to find a good commit for `git bisect`.  "detached HEAD" is the name of this state since HEAD is pointing directly to a commit rather than pointing to one indirectly via a particular ref.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What happens to git commits created in a detached HEAD state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984223/what-happens-to-git-commits-created-in-a-detached-head-state)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to get the commit hash of the commit that you did while in "no branch" ( a detached HEAD) and merge that in to the branch that you are currently in ( master maybe)

Something like `git merge HEAD@{1}`

You can also `git rebase -i` and "pick" the commit you want from the reflog.

Answer (score 12):

I was in a similar state after committing some work:

> Lilith:Manager KelSolaar$ git status
>
> ## Not currently on any branch.

I issued a **git log** to see my last commit hash:

> Lilith:Manager KelSolaar$ git log
>
> commit 49984303037e970d637161c3154b7fd7d6ae3a43
>   Author: KelSolaar 
>   Date:   Wed Oct 5 22:41:31 2011 +0100
>
> ```
> Introduce new "QObject" components category and rename existing ones to "Def
> ```

I then checked out my master branch:

> Lilith:Manager KelSolaar$ git checkout master
>
> Previous HEAD position was 4998430... Introduce new "QObject" components categorie and rename exising ones to "Default" and "QWidget".
>
> Switched to branch 'master'

And I finally merged using the commit hash:

> Lilith:Manager KelSolaar$ git merge 49984303037e970d637161
>
> Updating 141bc69..4998430
>
> Fast-forward
>
> src/manager/component.py                           |    2 +-
>
> ...

Answer (score 10):

`git checkout -` will switch you back to the previous branch:

```
Thu Feb 21 12:50 AM /src/test ((08f84f4...)) $ git checkout master

Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  08f84f4 Fix everything

Switched to branch 'master'

Thu Feb 21 12:50 AM /src/test (master) $ git checkout -

HEAD is now at 08f84f4... Fix everything

Thu Feb 21 12:50 AM /src/test ((08f84f4...)) $
```

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Also worth mentioning, you can check your current branch using `git branch`

Comment: This answers the question with the simplest solution.  `git checkout -` (just to highlight it again)

Answer (score 2):

Your commit isn't gone, you can recover by asking git to show you the hidden commits, and put them back in a temporary branch.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89332/recover-dropped-stash-in-git/91795#91795) for instructions.

Comment: It's easier than that in this case, since the reflog will have the commit - [manojlds's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048425/not-currently-on-any-branch-git-commit-checkout-when-not-in-any-branch-did-i/6048609#6048609) describes that.

Answer (score 2):

Use "git reflog" it shows the commit hashes of the results of your git command history.
You can then "git co hash" and when you've found the right one, set/make a branch for it.

Answer (score 0):

The example

[image: Branches list]

Here, I have just 1 local branch: main. The other branches are from origin.

Trying to checkout to a commit

[image: Click to checkout]

Message:

[image: message]

It is because that is a commit, not a branch. I clicked on Cancel

Creating a new branch

[image: Creating a new branch]

Trying to "checkout" the new branch to the commit

[image: checkout to the new branch]

Same result

[image: result 1]

Reset branch to this commit

[image: reset branch to this commit]

Pop up window

[image]

Result

[image: result - reset branch]

Same try with main (previously, checkout to main branch)

[image: reset main to a commit]

Result:

[image]

So, in my case, the desired behaviour was "Reset", not "Checkout"

I can reset a branch to any commit.

Answer (score -5):

You're never "not on any branch". You might have been on the branch called `master`, but you WERE on a branch when you committed. So that commit is SOMEWHERE.

Use `git log` to look at history. You can use `git reset` to go back in time (including, optionally, leaving the changes in your working directory).

Comment: This is wrong - you *can* not be on a branch.  This state is known as "detached HEAD" because `HEAD` points to a particular commit's hash rather than to a branch name.  Any commits you make with detached HEAD won't advance a branch tip, but will still be accessible for some time via the reflog.

Comment: Not true.  Right now "$ git status" gives me "# Not currently on any branch." (instead of the usual "# On branch master"), followed by "# Changes to be committed:" etc.