# Github - how to solve conflicts

Tags: version-control, github, xcode4.2, conflict

My friend and I are trying to work on an iPhone project, but have a problem with version conflict management using github.

Example: Both of us are working on a certain line of code with xCode 4.2 (and the github mac client)

```
int majorVersion = 0;
```

1) He changes the code to `int majorVersion = 999;` commits changes; syncs - no problems, will end up in github

2) Simultaneously, I change the code to `int majorVersion = 666;` then:

- I commit changes
- conflict - I choose my certain version by selecting line of code (`int majorVersion = 666;`)
- in xCode, I delete the funny <<<<<< HEAD bits (so that only `int majorVersion = 666;` remains)
- commit changes
- finally: **I try to Publish branch but get the following error:**

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination: HEAD The destination
>   refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor begins with
>   refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
>   error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/XXX/XXX.git'

What are we doing wrong? Is the main problem that I have deleted the funny <<<<< and the HEAD declaration in xCode (see screenshot below)? How are we supposed to handle such conflicts?

[image]

Comment: Use the command line `git` program. What does `git status` say? Did you commit your merge conflict resolution before trying to push?

Comment: @Daenyth: Yes, I tried to commit my merge conflict resolution before trying to push. Committing was not a problem. Pushing prompted the error. git status will log this to console: # Not currently on any branch.
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

Comment: Part of your issue is that you're using the GitHub Mac client. It looks nice, but doesn't really show branch structure very well. Try SourceTree or GitX for a better visualization of your repo.

Answer (score 1):

> Not currently on any branch. nothing to commit (working directory clean)
>   (as seen in [this example](http://pastie.org/pastes/1060476/text))

That means you are in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714), and resolutions (git log, git reflog, ...) are mentioned in "[Not currently on any branch + git commit + checkout when not in any branch. Did i loose my changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048425/not-currently-on-any-branch-git-commit-checkout-when-not-in-any-branch-did)".

The problem isn't the concurrent modification in itself, but rather how you did checkout your code in XCode4 in the first place: any checkout of a tag or a SHA1 would result in a detached head situation.

See also the resolution proposed in "[Git Checkout reverted code to older commit, how to revert back?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7263984/6309)".

Comment: Thanks for suggesting how to resolve the problem. However, I don't understand how I should have handled the situation in the first place. Instead of deleting the +<<<<<<<<<< and +=========== what exactly do I have to do?

Comment: No the delete part if good (it is how you solve a conflict). But before even starting making any modification (which or without conflict), you first need to be sure you have checked out a branch, and not a SHA1 or a tag. Otherwise you will have an issue when trying to commit.

Comment: Thanks a lot. We will give this another try and the one who has the conflict will make sure to check out the branch before committing.