# Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to any of your branches

Tags: git, version-control, branching-and-merging

EGit strikes again. I made the mistake of trying to switch to a different branch in EGit and it somehow messed up and checked out no branch. I then made a commit to this non-branch, and then when I realized I wasn't tracking the right branch, I ran the following:

```
$ git checkout issue2
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to any of your branches:

    bada553d My commit message

If you want to keep them by creating a new branch, this may be a good time to do so with:

    git branch new_branch_name ....

Branch issue2 set up to track remote branch issue2 from origin.
Switched to a new branch issue2.
```

Now that I've botched things, how do I associate that commit with my current branch? I'm not interested in creating a brand new branch, I just want to pull that commit into my branch, `issue2`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to git commits created in a detached HEAD state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984223/what-happens-to-git-commits-created-in-a-detached-head-state)

Comment: How can you be on "no branch" anyway...?

Comment: @JohnyTex  when people like me use git in weird ways.  Fortunately StackOverflow saves my bacon again!

Answer (score 141, accepted):

you can `git cherry-pick bada553d` if it's just the one commit.

You can also reference anywhere you've been by using the reflog:

```
git reflog
```

then use one of those commits:

```
git checkout -b temp HEAD@{3}
```

to checkout and make a branch temp from where your current commit was 3 "times" ago. It's a bread crumb of where you used to be.

Comment: How to delete commit like this which is not required?

Comment: If you don't give it a name, like a branch or tag, it'll eventually be deleted by git's garbage collector.

Comment: For multiple commits you can [cherry pick](https://www.tollmanz.com/git-cherry-pick-range/) [a](/a/1994491) range using `git cherry-pick ebe6942^..905e279`

Answer (score 20):

If you just want to associate that commit with your current branch, you can simply do this

1. Run this command to create a new branch with that commit

   **`git branch temp {commit's SHA}`**
2. Then simply merge this commit with your current branch

   **`git merge temp`**
3. Now just delete the temporary new branch we created

   **`git branch -d temp`**

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much. IMO this is more straightforward than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just apply tag to your commit after using `git reflog` when you'll know commit's hash:

```
 Git tag <tag's_name>  <commit's_hash>/HEAD@{<commit's_num>}
```