# How can one in Visual Studio open another GIT-branch without need to commit changes to the current one?

Tags: git, visual-studio

How do one use multiple branches or switch branch without commit?

I'm using GIT with VisualStudio and are working in one branch when a colleague of mine ask me to to something in another. I do not want to commit changes in my first branch. How do I use two branches simultaneously or how do I switch branches without committing pending changes?

Comment: you can [stash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) your work in your current branch, checkout the other branch, help your colleague, and the checkout your branch, and apply the stash content it again

Comment: You can also try `git worktree`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45491767/6330106

Answer (score 3):

When you have uncommitted changes in a branch and you want to switch to another branch you can use `git stash` to temporarily "save" the changes without committing them.

When you switch back to the branch you can use `git stash pop` to reapply your changes to the branch.

You can also do more advanced stuff with stash, see the [Git Pro book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing) Chapter about it for more.

If you are using Visual Studio 2019 you can stash directly [in the Team Explorer](https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2019/04/10/the-git-stash-functionality-in-visual-studio-2019/), for the 2017 version you can use [this extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vii.GitStashExtension) if you don't want to use the terminal.