# What if I have a "disconnected commit" in Git?

Tags: git

I don't even know how I got there. I just did a

```
git commit -am "Some kind of comment"
```

and git says:

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

When I did a `git branch`, it says:

```
* (HEAD detached from e36ed32)
  lazy-and-measure-time
  main
```

and I ignored it and just change back to main:

```
git checkout main
```

and now it says:

```
Warning: you are leaving 1 commit behind, not connected to
any of your branches:

  4294f76 Some kind of comment

If you want to keep it by creating a new branch, this may be a good time
to do so with:

 git branch <new-branch-name> 4294f76

Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
```

So fortunately, I still have the commit number `4294f76` and I was able to do a

```
git merge 4294f76
```

and merge it back to my `main`.

However,

1. what if I typed `clear` to clear the screen. How do I ever get back the number `4294f76` to do the merge above? It seems like a commit that is in the outer space not connected to anything.
2. How did I even get to this state, to have a commit no related to any branch?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984223/what-happens-to-git-commits-created-in-a-detached-head-state