# Fix git "not currently on any branch" after merge conflicts

Tags: git

I tried to commit the changes. After a lot of problems and conflicts, I managed to resolved every problem. However, the code I committed is not currently on any branch (as the `git status` shows). How can I fix this problem? I tried several solutions but none worked for me. I tried the command `git merge` but it says it's already up to date.

#### Update

The result of `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate` is:

```
* 7833c31 (HEAD) Changed LI tool
* c205a25 Fixed merge conflicts
*   7b10e48 (vsproj/master, master) 4-7-2013
|\  
| * cc51cb0 3/9/2013
| * 62ea718 Updated mail and added barcode
| * 9a3573a 1-7-2013
| * 96ded0e Updated ExamsPrinter
| * be6638a 12-25-2012
| * 89cba4b Added HTML to PDF and updated Email app
| * fa96aeb Updates
| * 9ffcfcc Changes in CloudDownloader, LinkedIn & Twitter apps
| * 609c555 Added README file
| * bf8a344 Started implementing CloudDownloader, created FileDownloader, updated FacebookInfoBot
| * c3556ce First Commit
* 3a59cd5 4-7-2013
```

Comment: You may need to explain how you got into merge conflict: `merge`, `pull`, `rebase`, `stash pop`, etc.  It looks like you are in the middle of a rebase.

Comment: please list the commands you ran

Comment: Well, I really don't know all the commands I ran. I just panicked, searched the web and ran a bunch of commands. I remember using `merge` and `pull` but I've not used `rebase` and `stash pop`. At first a lot of files got marked for conflict with `<<<<HEAD`... I wrote a simple program which solved the conflict automatically for me, then ran a checkout and now the repository is working again. However the only problem is that it's not on a branch.

Comment: Post the results of `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate`.

Comment: maybe this is helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048425/not-currently-on-any-branch-git-commit-checkout-when-not-in-any-branch-did

Comment: If you dont remember the commands, at least show us the log for your current state, and the log of the branch you were on. For ease of reading i suggest using the log command like this: `git log -5 --oneline HEAD` and `git log -5 --oneline <previous_branch>`

Comment: @jthill Thanks for the command. Posted the update.

Comment: If you're on a Linux system, the `history` command is useful to find out what happened while you panicked. Also, `git reflog` might refresh your memory. When it comes to "not on a branch", this (typically) means that you're in the middle of an operation. `git <command> --continue` is often the right option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure what happened, but you could fix it easily by creating a new branch and then merging it:

```
git branch lost_changes
git checkout master
git merge lost_changes
```

Comment: Awesome. I created, switched and merged the branches. Everything's fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So you can see on your history what's going on here.  You did a merge, producing

```
*   7b10e48 (vsproj/master, master) 4-7-2013
```

and then after explicitly disconnecting your checkout from the master branch tip%1 you committed

```
* c205a25 Fixed merge conflicts
```

and

```
* 7833c31 (HEAD) Changed LI tool
```

So to just make your current checkout the master branch tip you do

```
git checkout -B master HEAD
```

and that looks like the simplest recovery here.

Why did you explicitly commit merge conflicts? You have to tell git you've resolved them all (by `git add`ing the correct content) before it will accept the commit.

%1:  the usual way I get a no-ref "detached" checkout is `git checkout HEAD@{1}`, there are lots of ways, git's fairly casual about branch tips and so will you be after you get comfortable with what's going on here.

Comment: Thank you. The answer was very helpful. Although I already fixed the repository using @kan's method.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly aren't on a branch, the simple solution is to create a new branch as such:

```
git branch <name> 7833c31
```

or

```
git branch <name> HEAD
```

and the you can go about figuring out the problem or, hopefully, just continuting your development.