# VS Code Git clean recovery

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I accidentally hit Git clean command in Visual Studio code, and I lost all my files. Is there any way to recover my files? Tried to find files with recovery programs, but no results.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24671650/does-git-clean-support-moving-to-recycle-bin

Comment: gosh darn it. I voted to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41265844/11107541, then freaked out when I saw the visual-studio tag instead of visual-studio-code, cancelled by close-vote, then realized the tag was just wrong, fixed the tag, and now I can't close-vote again >:(

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, no, those files are gone. AFIK Git doesn't create any backup copyies.

According to [the source code of the clean command](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7974889a053574e449b55ca543a486e38e74864f/builtin/clean.c) it executes `unlink` when you hit this command.

Answer (score 0):

This answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24673982/2441655) suggests that running `git fsck --lost-found` may recover some files.