# Restore a deleted file in the Visual Studio Code Recycle Bin

Tags: visual-studio-code, recycle-bin

Using Visual Studio Code Version 1.8.1 how do I restore a deleted file in the recycle bin?

Comment: Since VS Code shows that hint inside the program I find this question very legit. I too looked for a minute inside of the program before googling (and landing here) and before looking in the system trash bin ;)

Comment: yes, this is a lacking feature

Comment: I recommend checking out [this underrated answer](https://superuser.com/a/1723403).

Comment: In addition to the recycle bin, check the own vscode backsup: `Local History: Find Entry to Restore`

Comment: The previous comment is by far the easiest solution. It looks to have been added [somewhat recently](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145461).

Answer (score 270):

It uses the normal trash bin of your system. So you can grab it our of there.

In Windows you find it in the explorer, in Linux it is as well in Konquerer / Nemo / ...

Comment: In Linux, you can restore using a terminal with the `trash-cli` package. `trash-list` will list all files in the trash, `trash-restore foo` let you guide you through restoring a file named foo. Useful in ChromeOS where there may be no GUI app with access to the Linux trash installed.

Comment: I arrived here because I accidentally rm'd an important file, trash-cli did the trick. You just litteraly saved me @Ray

Comment: For me the debugger wreaked havoc and deleted the folder. Nothing in the Recicle Bin. The tabs disapeared too.

Comment: Found it in one of  `%APPDATA%\Code\User\History`  subfolders though.

Comment: @Spartan You just saved me a bunch of time. I accidentally deleted my whole src folder instead of one of the subfolders and was able to recover the files that weren't in version control yet.

Comment: @Spartan You saved me days recoding it thanks a lot. This must be the most memorizable life saving I get from Stackoverflow

Comment: But be aware that only saved files occur in the History folder, deleted + unsaved files don't.

Answer (score 64):

1. First go to Recycle Bin of your local machine.
2. Your VS code deleted files is there in Recycle Bin.
3. So, Right click on deleted files and select-> Restore option then your deleted files 
   will be automatically restored in your VS code.

Comment: It actually works! I found all files in my recycle bin. Thanks man

Answer (score 49):

If you just deleted the file, know that [VSCode 1.52 (Dec. 2020)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/51d664f3442cc4f63821a9ab65e487374c9d7efe/release-notes/v1_52.md#undo-file-operations-in-explorer) will support:

> ### Undo file operations in Explorer

> **Explorer now supports Undo and Redo for all file operations: delete, rename, copy, move, new file and new folder**.
>
> Make sure the focus is in the Explorer and trigger the Undo or Redo commands and your last file operation will be undone or redone respectively.
> Keep in mind that we have separate undo stacks for the editor and the explorer and we choose which one to undo based on focus.
>
> [image: Explorer Undo -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_52/explorer-undo.gif]

Comment: This is especially relevant, as there's currently a bug in VSCode (or, more accurately, I think it's in Electron or some dependency) that causes VSCode to freeze when you trash a file, so some users have bypassed the "trash" file, and just straight up delete them.

Comment: Is there a way to disable that feature? Because now we can break the project because of an 'Undo' command executed incorrectly. Something can be undone inside the explorer panel and it can be confusing to understand what happened and why the project is broken, again, and again. We type cmd+z many times a day, you changed this feature that might lead us to undo something elsewhere we're not really looking at.

Comment: @rochasdv I don't see an undo setting related to this feature. So that would be a good request to record as an issue.

Comment: This was a lifesaver, accidentally deleted a file I'd just spent 20 minutes revising and hadn't committed yet and it didn't show up in the trash, but undo worked!

Comment: this. comment. has. saved. my. life. I. don't. know. how. to. thank. you.

Comment: saved my life! cmd+Z was not working but using the drop down worked!

Comment: Thanks, I was really in a panic for a bit after an accidental deletion. Saved me lots of time there. Note to self - breathe, breathe....

Answer (score 35):

Click in empty space of VS Code's explorer (it's where you see files listed vertically) and press undo `Ctrl + z`

**It'll recover your permanently deleted files too.**

VS Code is a lifesaver. ✌

Comment: This. This VERY HINT saved my life (or my recent changes, or whatever). *In an empty space, where you see files listed vertically*. PHEW, thank you!!

Comment: THIS SOLUTION SAVED A TWO-DAYS-WORK AND MY SANITY

Comment: Don't know what empty space you mean... I've tried to click every single fragment, but it does not help. Nothing is happening... Damn....

Comment: @Alexander Click inside the file explorer of the VS code. It usually sits on the left side and you see files listed vertically. And then press undo. If you have restarted VS code in the meanwhile then it might not be possible anymore.

Comment: @lockhrt it did not help. Probably it works for a separate file. In my case - I've deleted a whole folder...

Comment: oh this worked for AWS instance.. even it was permanently deleted.

Comment: Wow. like a 5hours before I delete a file in a folder. then have been doing a lot in the vscode. at a moment i needed it again. was not in bin. selected that folder in left side panel and did a ctrl+Z, tada, it came back. saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 26):

This worked for me!

1. Try to recreate files (with extensions - files should be empty) and directory structure.
2. There should be a **`TIMELINE`** on the left side of the bottom VSC `EXPLORER` view (default setting).
   [image: VSC timeline view]
3. Right click on **the last** `File Saved`, then choose **`Restore Contents`**.
   [image: VSC timeline view - with opened context menu]

*Hope it saves someone like it saved me 3 hours of life!*

If not, I recommend trying the way described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72706798/10717179) (by [@iutlu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10968281/) [remote development] and [@Spartan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/802494/)) - it was helpful to me, only that there were a lot of versions of each file - but I'm not saying no: the files were!

Comment: This should get more upvotes! Just discovered the same thing myself and posted the same answer only to stumble upon this one!

Comment: you saved me. thank you very much!

Comment: You can also F1 > "Local History: Find Entry to Restore" and search for the name of the deleted file. However, maybe because I was using remote SSH, when I selected the file, it simply showed it to me, instead of actually restoring it. I had to copy the contents.

Comment: this only saved about 50 hours of work.. wow thank you soo much

Comment: I was able to restore two days of working thanks to your tip.

Comment: Great!!!!  The magic tip was to recreate the folder and the file (empty thus) then using Outline, it's possible to retrieve his history, before the error (rm the file). Thanks!

Comment: You are the goat for this 

Answer (score 23):

Running on Ubuntu 18.04, with VS code 1.51.0

My deleted files from VS Code are located at:

**`~/.local/share/Trash/files`**

Every deleted file have a corresponding `.trashinfo` file which contains details about where the file is deleted from and deletion date and these are located at:

**`~/.local/share/Trash/info`**

More info [here](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html).

To search for your deleted files:

```
find ~/.local/share/Trash/files -name your_file_name
```

In case you deleted files form a mounted ntfs filesystem, they will be located at:

**`/path_to_mounted_fs/.Trash-$UID`**

You can get `$UID` by doing `echo $UID` in your terminal.

Hope my case helped!

Comment: Haha, this is the best SO post in a very very long time for me. I would've given 20 up votes if I could.

Answer (score 20):

If you can't find your files in the Windows Recycle Bin as it happended to me
(debugger went rogue and deleted the project folder)
look in the `%APPDATA%\Code\User\History\` subfolders sorted by date modified.
There I could retrieve my seemingly lost files.

Comment: And if you're using remove development, `~/.vscode-server/data/User/History` --> grep through the files there

Comment: @iutlu Your comment worked for me. You are a life saver. Please considering posting your comment so many other people can benefit from it.

Comment: Spent ages trying to look it undelete options for WSL/ubuntu and few looked promising. However Spartan/iutlu is exactly what I needed. Life saved.

Answer (score 15):

I know the OP says Recycle Bin. What I do though is recreate the file, especially if it's a single file. And when in the file, I just press CMD+Z (I'm on a Mac) and I get my file back.

1. Recreate the file in the same directory from where it was
   deleted.
2. CMD+Z inside of the newly created file.

Comment: This did not work for me but made it worse ...

Comment: You can also see the changes in the Timeline section.

You can create a new file with the same file name, and the VS Code Timeline will show the content from before it was deleted.

Answer (score 10):

I accidentally discarded changes in the Source Control in VS Code, I just needed to reopen this file and press Ctrl-Z few times, glad that VS Code saves your changes like that.

Answer (score 9):

who still facing the problem on linux 
and didnt find it on trash
try this solution

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32078#issuecomment-434393058

```
find / -name "delete_file_name"
```

Comment: Life saving! Thanks a lot! <3

Answer (score 7):

If you have permanently deleted files, on macOS, you can see the history (the last month I guess) in `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/History/`. You will have to find your file(s) by looking at each `entries.json` file in every subfolder and rename the last version of your file.

There is probably a similar way on windows and linux but I don't know the precise paths.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @MajorTom, in my case I lost the files from VSCode. In **entries.json** there's a reference to the original file, where every log is a snapshot with a timestamp. These _tsx_ files contains the file state at given time.
`code
"entries" :[
    { "id": "S17j.tsx", "timestamp": 1663258186343 },
    { "id": "A8Ql.tsx", "timestamp": 1663329533427 },    
  ]
`

Answer (score 6):

I tried most of the options above but none worked.

What worked for me was clicking and **highlighting the folder where the file was deleted** from in vscode. Then while it is **selected**, hit `CTRL + Z`.
This works on windows.

Hitting CTRL+Z without highlighting that folder didn't work.

Comment: I tried that, It recovered the folder which the debugger deleted and the last written file in it, not more. The rest i found in `%APPDATA%\Code\User\History`

Answer (score 4):

VS Code saves any file you actually edit - not all files in a project directory however - to a local directory :

Linux : $HOME/.config/Code/User/History
Mac : ~/Library/Application Support/Code/History
Windows : %APPDATA%\Code\User\History\

There are directories created for every file you edit with different versions tied to a timestamp/session defined in a JSON file called entries.json like [@MajorTom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4613734/majortom) mentioned so your work is saved but it is a tad bit cumbersome to restore a directory like you would restoring from the trash.

If you simply want to restore the latest version of a directory you accidentally deleted, you can run this .net console utility and it will restore everything it possibly can to a directory you
specify in the appsettings.json.

https://github.com/karlpothast/VSCodeRecoveryTool

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34505223)

Answer (score 4):

It's not quite clear what "recycle bin" means here since I don't understand why it would be difficult to restore something from there (as in- your system's trash/recycling bin/folder/directory or whatever it's called. VS Code itself doesn't have an analogous feature built-in (though it does have something you might find even better)).

When deleting files from VS Code's Explorer View, they do go to the system's trash folder by default [since version 0.5.0](/a/30558679/11107541) (see also the `files.enableTrash` setting. Though I think on some systems there's an exception for deleting directories recursively, such as on Linux), and most systems' default file explorer applications will provide an easy way to restore the file to its original location from the system's trash folder.

But since this Q&A has been interpreted quite freely by the community and become what looks like a canonical, I'll try to give the best canonical answer I can.

#### VS Code Explorer Undo

As stated, if the last modification you made in the Explorer View was to delete something, [since version 1.52 of VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_52#_undo-file-operations-in-explorer), you can just focus the Explorer View and press the "Undo" keyboard shortcut (<kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) and the deletion will be undone. See also the `explorer.enableUndo` and `explorer.confirmUndo` settings. This works for files, but I don't think it works for directories.

See also the `explorer.confirmDelete` setting.

#### Version Control Software

If you're using some form of version control such as Git, and the last version of the file has been saved in some way (Ex. Git stage or commit), and the internals of the VCS are still intact (you haven't deleted them too), then you can just use your VCS's mechanisms for pulling that saved copy into the working directory.

For example for Git, see the following:

- [How do I find and restore a deleted file in a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/953481/11107541)
- [git recover deleted file where no commit was made after the delete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11956710/11107541)
- [Recover from losing uncommitted changes by "git reset --hard"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5788037/11107541)

Or if you've pushed the changes you want to some other remote, you can fetch them back from there.

#### VS Code Local History (for files with no unsaved changes)

Since version 1.66, VS Code also has a feature to keep a history of files you were working on in it: [Local History](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_66#_local-history). It saves a copy every time you save the file (well, not exactly. There are settings to control its behaviour that you can find in the Settings UI). The release notes list the commands that the feature supports, and the settings you can use to configure it. But what you probably want at this moment is the command `Local History: Find Entry to Restore` (run in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)), which opens a menu listing all the history entries, with a searchbar. The ID for that command is `workbench.action.localHistory.restoreViaPicker`.

I think you could also create a new file with the same name and path in place of the one you deleted, and view the Local History entries also in the Timeline View (a subview of the Explorer View), which you can focus using the `Explorer: Focus on Timeline View` command in the command palette.

If you find some reason to want to dig around, the Local History feature saves the history entries in files under the `User/History` subdirectory of the user data directory (you can specify a user data directory via commandline using the `--user-data-dir` commandline argument, but the default one is in a OS-dependent location, which is also [where your user settings.json file goes under](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settings-file-locations)):

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code`
- macOS `$HOME/Library/Application\ Support/Code`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code`
- For VS Code Server, the default user data directory should be `~/.vscode-server/data`

Just be warned that the file names are not human-readable, so bring a commandline search tool with you like grep or something.

Some interesting notes from my brief experimentation with the feature: It seems like if VS Code is open with a workspace folder containing file A while you modify file A from some other program and write that modification to disk, it will still be recorded by VS Code. Also, the `workbench.localHistory.exclude` setting (which is empty by default) does not inherit from the `files.exclude` setting as is the case for other similar features like `search.exclude`. So if you manually edit files under `./.git/`, even they will have local history entries! But (approximately) I don't think files that have ever been moved around or manually saved will have a history entry even if they are changed outside of VS Code until one of those things happens.

If you're interested, the full logic for whether something should be tracked by Local History is implemented in [src/vs/workbench/services/workingCopy/common/workingCopyHistoryTracker.ts](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/src/vs/workbench/services/workingCopy/common/workingCopyHistoryTracker.ts).

If you're using a version of VS Code prior to 1.66, you could use an extension. Try searching "local history" in the VS Code marketplace or Extensions View and take your pick. Of course, nothing will be saved by an extension until that extension has been installed on your machine, so if you didn't install them before losing your files, this won't help you with your immediate problem.

#### VS Code Hot Exit (for files with unsaved changes)

VS Code also has [a feature called "Hot Exit"](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_hot-exit) that remembers files that you didn't save before closing the VS Code window.

If you want to dig around, the storage for this feature goes under the "Backups" directory in the user data directory.

#### If you can't do any of that...

I think you're left with looking into data recovery. Ex.

- SuperUser [How do I recover lost/inaccessible data from my storage device?](https://superuser.com/q/241817/1749748)
- Unix&Linux [Recovering accidentally deleted files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2677/550426)
- Unix&Linux [How to recover files I deleted now by running rm *?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/101237/550426)

Comment: Upvoted: this is more complete than my [answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74542865/6309).

Comment: Saved me hours of work.

Answer (score 3):

Just look up the files you deleted, inside Recycle Bin. Right click on it and do restore as you do normally with other deleted files. It is similar as you do normally because VS code also uses normal trash of your system.

Answer (score 2):

While pushing a repository to Github through **Vs Studio code** I deleted whole folder and they were **not available in Recycle bin also**. Here is how I recovered those files.
**For Windows**.

> The method is to **restore the previous version of the Drive** in which the deleted file existed

I had deleted files from G: drive, the below images are self explanatory

> Open properties menu of the drive

[image]

> In properties go to previous versions tab,
> where you can find the previously stored versions of that drive along with date at time of backup
> use open or click on restore to get the previous version of that drive.

[image]

> Note: Manipulations in the drive after restore point won't be available

Comment: Hi I am facing the same issue but in my case, there is no previous version

Comment: It will not work if your  File history is turned off and you won't be able to recover.

Comment: @SaadAbbasi I had tried for 2 days but this restoring the previous versions is the only solution I found

Comment: Unfortunately, my file history was not enabled so I was not able to recover. I am going to do all stuff again. :(

Comment: Can I enable File history option without an external  drive? I want to enable it

Comment: @SaadAbbasi Not sure of those things but here I have some resources which might help         [link](https://www.wintips.org/enable-or-disable-system-restore-windows/), [link](wintips.org/fix-restore-previous-versions-not-working-in-windows-10/) this might work  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how I deleted a file in VS Code, and couldn't find it in recycle bin. Found the file using the History feature of File Explorer.

[image: File Explorer Options]

[image: File Explorer File History]

[image: File History is on]

Comment: Good tip, i found that vscode has its own history folder at `%APPDATA%\Code\User\History` should the feature be disabled...

Answer (score 2):

A month recovery can be done in visual studio code
1 Right click on file and
2 click Open Timeline and
3 select file from timeline
4 the last time file saved by you
5 and your last change of the file is recovered

NOTE : Not only last but all the previously saved check points can be recoverd from vs code

Comment: Hard to right click on a file that is deleted ;)

Comment: You can create a new file with the same file name, and the VS Code Timeline will show the content from before it was deleted.

Comment: how can you do this on an entire folder?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on Windows with a Ubuntu WSL. I permanently deleted a file by mistake and was not able to restore it from the recycle bin nor by doing anything else.

I however, was able to get my files content by going to **"Timeline"** and see all my previous modification (it will open a comparison window).

Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac, try to search some parts of the code in the deleted file in the following path:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code
```

I found a deleted file in this folder

```
~/Library/Application Support/Code/Backups
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the case that I, accidentally, deleted a committed file (git) with a ton of additional uncommitted changes, and I could not get it back. (two days of work! yeah, I know, commit early commit often, I know ...)

I had no linux trash can setup on my docker instance and was developing via remote ssh.

I tried to recreate the file and then do a ctrl+Z to recapture the changes as some suggested here. This did not work for me.

So after a struggle over an hour I finally gave up and thought the changes to the file were lost.

However,

1. I discarded the changes in git, that the file was deleted.
2. And **THEN** I retried ctrl+Z and boom all the changes previously came back
   magically!

I was a happy camper!

Answer (score 1):

**EASY FIX**

If you know the name of the deleted file then recreate it with the exact name and filepath. Open the file, then go to **TIMELINE** as shown in the image below, you'll find all the changes you made to the file.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xbvlp.png)

Answer (score 1):

Like two other comments said

1. You can press F1 inside VS CODE
2. Write your file name
3. Select data version of file

done!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Vscode, stores a copy your recently edited file in local history, I created a [simple package](https://github.com/omkarcloud/vscode-deleted-file-recovery) that will help you find lost files.

**Usage**

1. **Install:**

```bash
pip install vscode_deleted_file_recovery
```

2. Create a Python file anywhere on your PC and run the following code to search for files:

```py
from vscode_deleted_file_recovery import Recover
Recover.print_files(search_term="/Chetan/Documents/tasks")  # Replace with your desired search path
```

3. Run the following code to restore deleted files. A folder named `_recovery` will be created in the same directory where you run it:

```py
from vscode_deleted_file_recovery import Recover
Recover.restore_files(search_term="/Chetan/Documents/tasks")  # Replace with your desired search path
```

You can find restored files in the `Recovery` folder where you ran the command.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I know this question is about VS Code but I think I can help someone.
I permanently deleted a file, and I tried all the tips wrote here with no success. So I had to recover the file from OS Linux following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373893/202811)

```
grep -a -C 500 -F 'Unique string in text file' /dev/sda
```

Answer (score 0):

It was asked above if there is a way to disable the ability to delete a file you created with an undo (@rochasdv).

There is a new setting to disable undo for file operations:

`Explorer: Enable Undo` default is `warn`, confirmation dialog

You can also set it to `disable` so that your files/folders will not participate in undo operations.

You can alo set it to `allow` - the pre-new setting situation.

Currently, this new setting is in the Insiders Build v1.64 so it may be in Stable early February, 2022.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the deleted files, after running

> **Run**

in order, you can see the changes you have made before using

> APPDATA%\Code\User\History\

path. By the way, you have the opportunity to examine the files according to the recording dates.

Answer (score 0):

If the deleted folder from vscode on a macbook is present in One Drive (Which is a common thing for software professionals) the deleted folder will not be in Recycle bin and rather in One Drive home folder.

Answer (score -1):

If your local directory has git initialized and you have not committed the changes that include the delete, you can use `git checkout -f` to throw away local changes.

Answer (score -2):

If you completely delete any of the components in angular using visual code, you can restore it
Go to Recycle Bin and restore the deleted component that will be restored in the project.