# Versioning in Visual Code Studio hid/deleted my local files on my Hard Drive

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, visual-studio-code, version-control

I was trying to change the versioning in visual code studio as it was showing my desktop as master, I found "master" green icon, when I clicked on the "X" sign next to it more than 500 files shown in the versioning control pane have disappeared when I clicked on the X sign , but the folders on my desktop still exist.
How can I recover my missing files.

I tried " git checkout master"

and I got ==> Already on 'master' Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'

Also, I tried VCS documentation and FAQs, but I couldn't find a clear answer to my question

Comment: possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41265844/11107541

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a stray `.git` folder either on your desktop or in your profile home directory.  This is likely what caused this.  Once you get it solved (or give up), find that stray `.git` folder and delete it.

To your specific question, I suspect you deleted untracked changes when you clicked the Red X.  Without a screen shot, I'm unable to replicate your results.  But sadly, you probably need to go to the last backup of your machine and restore the files.

It's also not clear.  Are you using "Visual Studio" or "VS Code"?  And which version?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply......Actually I am using Visual Studio Code...Yes I clicked on the red X as well....

Comment: I have been using the commands in the version control in Visual Studio Code drop down menu....I can see now the 5000 files which were originally showing under Changes in Visual Studio Code with the letter "U" in green next to each file

Comment: Just wanted to add that the original folders that contain the disappeared files still exist.