# I accidentally deleted my python venv folder on vs code, what should i do?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I accidentally deleted my python venv folder on vs code, i had tried some tutorials i could find on the internet but none of them works. Anyone know how to restore or redownload the venv file? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore a deleted file in the Visual Studio Code Recycle Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265844/restore-a-deleted-file-in-the-visual-studio-code-recycle-bin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once removed it's not possible to restore it once deleted, you can try to do Ctrl + z to see if it shows up again but you will have to reinstall all your modules

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you removed the folder, if via any file manager(nautilus, vscode itself, etc.) it could be found in a "Trash" or "Recycle Bin" folder and easily restored. However, if you deleted it with `rm` command, then it's gone from your machine.

 If you are in need of creating a venv folder - visit vscode [Using Python environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) on this matter.