# Accidentally delete file in visual studio code with remote ssh and cannot ctrl+z in Explorer View

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I used ubuntu and ssh by shh-remote extension to another ubuntu server, and I accidentally deleted a folder containing important files by pressing the delete key. I pressed "ctrl+z" but it did not restore.
What did vsc actually do?
How did I recover the deleted files (either by Visual Studio Code or by another way)?

update:
I use testdisk to recover but it show "ok" quite low, and "failed" quite high?
Many thanks.

Comment: Simply recover them from backup, or from version control. As you seem to be working with source code, I'm assuming you have both. Alternatively: Next time this happens, this likely has taught you enough to have both of them then. (and I mean this with love, not sarcastically - many have been there - me included. And having been there, we all have learned that "tomorrow" is not a good answer for when to start with backups and source control. Because "tomorrow" is the day of your next failure, and you should prepare for tomorrow _today_ - latest)

Comment: I would dup hammer this to https://stackoverflow.com/q/41265844/11107541, but this seems to be about a remote extensions bug that affected some concrete range of releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot recover files you have deleted with SSH through the VSCode editor built-in properties like Ctrl-Z. Operations on the disk are the responsibility of the operating system.

If you have not GUI acces to OS maybe you can look at the

> ls /home/$USER/.local/share/Trash

or if your files deleted with root privileges

> ls /root/.local/share/Trash

If your files are not deleted permanently you can restore with Trash-CLI program:

> sudo apt install trash-cli

then put this command to terminal

> trash-restore

If your files deleted permanently check this link for file recovery:

[How to Recover Deleted Files in Ubuntu Through TestDisk](https://vitux.com/how-to-recover-deleted-files-in-ubuntu-through-testdisk/)

Answer (score 6):

VS code actually fixed this and you can now un-delete a file while in an SSH remote session using CTRL + Z

If you're here cause you think you can't do give it a try!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

VSC also has a Timeline feature, which is basically a local version control system. In my case, it was enough to recreate the files in the same directory and with the same name, and then open the Timeline function. Then you can see different snapshots of the file (not only git commits) and easily restore the last save.

More here: [Docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview#_timeline-view)

Comment: This just saved me 4 hours of work. I am working in a VSCode-server container and accidentially hit "Delete permanently" in the explorer. I was a bit hesitant creating an empty file with the old name, but it worked perfectly using the timeline!