# File Recovery from Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I recover deleted files from recycle bin on Visual Studio Code?

I checked all the features but I couldn't find a solution. I checked the setting options and the help option but all to no avail.

Comment: Why did you tag `git`? Are you using git?

Comment: You mean that you tried the 'Timeline' tab? https://www.amitmerchant.com/vs-code-timeline-your-local-version-control-system/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restore a deleted file in the Visual Studio Code Recycle Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265844/restore-a-deleted-file-in-the-visual-studio-code-recycle-bin)