# Recover Xamarin form deleted folder

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, macos-sierra

Sorry for my question : I have delete a folder in my visual studio MAC 17.5.4 (build 8) Xamarin forms

Please how can I recover it, the folder is not in the bin

I have read this but without success : [Restore a deleted file in the Visual Studio Code Recycle Bin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265844/restore-a-deleted-file-in-the-visual-studio-code-recycle-bin)

Sorry again for my question