# How to recover deleted files from create vite react project

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, vite, restore

I've started to use Vite to craete React project for the first time. I followed a 2023 tutorial video on youtube. I'm using macos.

There were many projects in **Webapps** folder and I created a new folder for a Vite project where the directory structure was like this:

```
Webapps
|- project A
|- project B
|- ...
|- Vite project
```

After I opened the Vite project folder using VS Code and opened the terminal and then typed the command `npm create vite@latest` then selected React with javascript language. I forgot to type `./` after the command. Then I typed `npm create vite@latest ./` and selected React with javascript language again. This time, the terminal asked me will I deleted existing files in the directory or not? at the moment I understood that it will delete the recently created project using Vite.

After I said yes, the new folder in the project couldn't be opened I thought the error may occur, so I closed the VS code program and then reopen the project again. But I noticed that the existing projects in the **Wepapps** folder are gone. And there's no any project file in the trash. I wanted to recover all of the losing files, any ideas or suggestions?

This is the current files inside the **Webapps** folder:
[Webapps folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFXBF.png)

I want to ask for any ideas and suggestions to recover the deleted files from using Vite command in  the terminal.

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/a/77663826/11107541 answer your question?