Accidentally discarded all changes in Git repository, including files not added to .gitignore
I encountered a problem while working with Git in Visual Studio Code. Here's the situation:

I initialized a new Git repository in my project directory.
I added all files using git add ., but mistakenly forgot to add node_modules to the .gitignore file.
I added the line node_modules to the .gitignore file and attempted to commit the changes.
Unfortunately, I mistakenly terminated the terminal session without fully understanding a popup that appeared.
When I opened a new terminal session and tried to add the changes again using git add ., I received a message indicating that there were active changes in the repository.
In an attempt to resolve this, I clicked the "discard changes" button in the Git section of the sidebar without fully understanding the consequences.
As a result, I lost all my files except for node_modules.

Is there any way to recover my lost files? I've tried checking the Git history using commands like git reflog and git log, but I couldn't find any trace of my files. I'm not sure if I committed the changes before discarding them. Are there any other steps I can take to recover my lost files? Any help please.
I tried
$ git log --oneline --graph

* c65d0e7 (HEAD -> master) init


I'm using Visual Studio Code as my code editor.
My operating system is Windows.
I'm relatively new to Git and may not fully understand all its features and commands.


what is the output of git status? Just in case.... if you had added the files, you might be able to get the files content from the blobs that were added to the git object DB from git add.... even if that is not a process for the faint of heart (given that the blobs are just the contents of the files, but you would not know what is the path for each blob). If status tells you anything about deleted files and so on, you might be able to get the files from index (which should not be too difficult.... git restore can be used for that).

$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean

Ok. git log --oneline --graph and git reflog. (please, add this information to the original question, not as comments).

Then, what is the output of git ls-tree -r c65d0e7?

A bunch of file names like this 100644 blob c6eb4a91bc914b2cb46f1e09117af3a4774f4d44    node_modules/escape-string-regexp/package.json But as i viewed all those was files i added to the .gitignore i have them now.

So, only files inside node_modules are listed there? None of the files you are interested in?

Yes, like that.

Well... then it's time to go for the lifesaver..... You need to do it through the object DB from the blobs of the files you had added before. Let me try to find a recipe for that.... give me a second

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560184/recover-dangling-blobs-in-git Make a backup of the whole repo (like, the whole .git directory) before doing anything.... if you are able to recover what you want, consider deleting the backup.

There are a few things that I don't quite get. You never mentioned git commit, yet, I see that you have a commit init. Also, why are you saying that you lost your files. Don't you see the files there from your system file browser?

You have 4 good ways (3 using command line and 1 with a GUI) to recover staged files in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853981/717372

I have restored all the files, well i don't if it is all, but i have found 429 files after running git fsck --lost-found And now i just need to rename them, Thank you guys for your help.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77663826/11107541
