# Git Recover local repository - accidentally did git clean -f -d

Tags: git

I had personal branch `tmp-work` along with `mainline` branch and wanted to do clean resynchronized of mainline branch in my local repository. After running the command

```
git fetch origin && git reset --hard origin/mainline && git clean -f -d
```

my `tmp-work` branch is no longer there. It was not pushed to a remote repository. Is there any way to recover it on MacOS? I ran Mac data recover without success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I undo a \`git clean -fdx\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-undo-a-git-clean-fdx)

Comment: Nothing here should have deleted a local branch.  Possibly the [data recovery](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery#Data-Recovery) documentation will have some suggestions.

Comment: Was something committed on `tmp-work`? If not, did you atleast `git add` those files? If not, then you're out of luck. Git won't have those files.

Answer (score -1):

**I can be wrong: so, important, first do a backup of your git local repository (zip/tar/copy...) !**

you should find your last commit SHA1 for your working branch in tmp-work with the command:

```
git reflog
```

then try and run (until you find the good SHA1):

```
git checkout <SHA1>
```

and finally:

```
git reset --hard
```

or:

```
git checkout -b <new branch name>
```

Comment: Those files was untracked by git, you can't restore them using git commands.

Comment: oh, I though he commited the change to tmp-work and that he lost those commits (detached/unreachable) due to the "git reset --hard". Of course if nothing was commited then all is erased. (and tracked changes were already erased with the reset --hard)