# Git restore ignore files, removed all ignore files using git clean -fX

Tags: git

I have executed a command.
git clean -fX (which removes ignore files)

I want to restore them, please let me know how to restore removed files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I undo a \`git clean -fdx\`?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-undo-a-git-clean-fdx)

Answer (score 0):

If those ignored files were never previously added to the index (but only private, local to your repo), then there is no "git way" to get them back.

You would have to use some disk file analysis program to try and restore them.
Also, if you are using an IE like Eclipse, check if its [local history might still have a trace of those files](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2FgettingStarted%2Fqs-55.htm) (for you [to restore](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-87b.htm)).