# Git removed all files

Tags: git, git-flow, git-reset

I just initialized a repository by applying

```
git flow init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:folder/project.git
git add .
```

I noticed that I needed to comment on a folder, then used

```
git reset --hard
```

And tried to add the folder to `.gitignore`, but **all folders that were untracked have been removed**, after that I used

```
git clean -f -d
```

And now I have nothing, I lost my whole project and I don't know how to restore it.

Comment: Are you using any IDE, like Eclipse, Visual Studio or something? Maybe the IDE has some backup on Local History. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-undo-a-git-clean-fdx

Comment: Thanks!, i see that not are solution, i deleted my own project

Comment: `reset` and `--hard` both sound dangerous... I always check documentation for this, still after years of using GIT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking why all your project is gone, so let's break down the `git` commands you ran:

1. `git flow init` is roughly equivalent to `git init` and committing an empty "Initial commit" with a develop branch forked from master.
2. `git remote add ...` added your GitLab remote as a local remote so you can push/pull with it.
3. `git add .` added everything in the local directory `.` to your *staging area*, where they're ready to be committed. All good so far!
4. `git reset --hard` is where you ran into trouble. [The git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) shows that `--hard` *resets the index and working tree*, so **any changes to tracked files are discarded**. This means that everything you just added is reverted to their state in the last commit, an empty commit, so your files were deleted.
5. `git clean -f -d` just forcefully removes untracked directories, of which I expect you had none after the hard reset.

In the future, I suggest reading the docs for `git reset` so you learn why it works that way with `--hard`. For the record, what you wanted to run here was probably just `git reset` without any arguments, which would have unstaged all of your staged changes, but not deleted any code. Then, your other commands (such as editing `.gitignore`) would have behaved like you expected.

Comment: Also committing or stashing untracked code, even if the code is temporary, will help undo removals caused by a reset.