# How to restore files deleted with git clean -f -x?

Tags: github, git-branch, git-bash

After using `git clean -f -x` I have lost some important files. Is there any way to get them back or at least can I check which files I have lost so that I can add them separately from other directories?

Comment: What did you run `git clean` in the first place if you knew you had some content you didn't want erased?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I did it by mistake as most of the files were not important. I missed one which was important.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I undo a \`git clean -fdx\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-undo-a-git-clean-fdx)

Answer (score 2):

`git clean` is similar to `rm`; it deletes the files from the file system. You can't undo the operation except by using a file system recovery utility of some kind.

Comment: thanks for your response. Can I check though which files I have lost? I have run that on a git local branch using command line.

Comment: I don't know of a way, git doesn't write to a log when it performs an operation. I think you need to treat this the same way you would if you accidentally deleted a file (i.e. check a backup, or use some fancy software - not sure what operating system you're using but [example](https://www.linux.com/learn/get-your-data-back-linux-based-data-recovery-tools))

Comment: It's Windows 10 OS