# Git Opposite of git clean -f -d -x command

Tags: git, git-clean

We have done shelv in intelljIDEA and after that we performed git clean -f -d -x and we lost all the changes. How to retrieve my lost files.

Comment: You cannot retrieve files you deleted with `git clean -f -d -x` using `git`, they're gone unless you have a backup.

Comment: What do you mean by `shelv`? There's no such git command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I restore deleted files (undo a \`git clean -fdx\`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-restore-deleted-files-undo-a-git-clean-fdx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clean%5D+undo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. `git clean -fdx` deletes all files permanently, so unless these files were stored anywhere else they are gone permanently.