# How to restore the files that removed with the git command 'git clean -fdx'

Tags: git, macos, file, git-clean

I was so stipud run that command `git clean -fdx`, and lots of my untracked files had been removed. I searched google again and again for any solutions, but it seems there is no way to get back those removed files by git.

I guess there may be two ways to restore the removed files:

1. As most of my files are *.js, and they were cached in Chrome browser, so is it possible to view the contents of those cached files?
2. Restore the removed files with the file system. as my computer is Mac, so how can I do this in mac os?

Or is there any way else to restore those files?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I restore deleted files (undo a \`git clean -fdx\`)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-restore-deleted-files-undo-a-git-clean-fdx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-clean%5D+undo