# Files deleted after using git clean fr

Tags: git, github

any ideas to recover them on mac, or they are all gone

I was trying to unstage a particular repo but i mistakely did it on my root folder instead of my dub folder

Comment: If you wanted to unstage files, why use `git clean`?

Comment: [According to this SO, your non-tracked files are gone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267180/can-i-restore-deleted-files-undo-a-git-clean-fdx) (rip) - but As you're on macOS you _might_ be able to use Time Machine (or iCloud?) if you had your git repos in a monitored location.

Comment: BTW, don't feel _too bad_ about this - I think of unintentionlly losing files by running `git` commands without knowing what they do is a modern-day _rite of passage_: fortunately the good news is that you won't be doing it again (I hope!)

Comment: BTW (again), the `git` reference lists `clean` as an _Administration_ command, which means you normally shouldn't ever need to use it (along with `git gc` and `git fsck`).