# git stash apply can't get the version what i really need

Tags: git, git-stash

At first branch is in master,then

(1) `git checkout -b test1` ,then modify one file a.c,and `git stash`

And now git stash list

```
stash@{0}: WIP on test1: 7aa1dbd Merge "RR:AA123"
```

(2)`git checkout -b test2`,then modify another file b.c,and `git stash`

And now git stash list

```
stash@{0}: WIP on test2: 7aa1dbd Merge "RR:AA123"
stash@{1}: WIP on test1: 7aa1dbd Merge "RR:AA123"
```

(3) now `git checkout test`,and i'd like to get the modified a.c file,which was in `stash@{1}`

```
 git stash apply --stash@{1},
```

and found get the b.c but not a.c

do i miss some steps that try to get stash pop?

Answer (score 4):

You should  use

```
git stash apply stash@{1}
```

NOT

```
git stash apply --stash@{1}
```

`--stash@{1}` will be ignored as an invalid option, so it is equal to `git stash apply`

Comment: fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions

Comment: @liumilan It is `stash@{1}` not `stash@1`

Comment: I change shell from tsch to bash ,now git stash apply stash@{1}
can work.Why it can't work in tsch?

Comment: @liumilan from the error message, tsch convert `stash@{1}` to `stash@1`. And why this happend, I really not know.

Comment: I don't use `tcsh`, but I imagine the shell is interpreting the curly braces.  You could probably single quote the argument and that would work: `git stash apply 'stash@{1}'`.

Comment: This answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6468931/602716) explains how the different shells handle the braces.