# Using curly braces referencing git revisions/references fails

Tags: git, shell, zsh

I am trying to checkout a single file from stash:

```
git checkout stash@{0} -- some/file
```

This fails with `fatal: invalid reference: stash@0`

Looks like the curly braces are eliminated, but I am not sure about the culprit.

The stash revision is there. `git stash list` returns

```
stash@{0}: WIP on X
stash@{1}: WIP on Y
```

I am using git 1.9.1 on zsh.

Is there a way to prevent this brace elimination?

Comment: It is generally better to quote strings with `{..}` sequences (e.g., `git checkout 'stash@{0}' ...`, as they can be interpreted as brace expansions. However, in `zsh` I would _not_ expect that to be the source of the problem here, because `{0}` is _not_ a valid brace expression and thus simply printed as is; verify with `print stash@{0}`.

Comment: Do you have suspicious stuff in your environment? (output of $ env)

Comment: `{0}` is not a valid brace expansion for bash either.

Comment: `print stash@{0}` prints prints `stash@0` - strange

Comment: @mklement0 - quoting the ref worked fine, thanks. care to post as an answer? I am still wondering however what causes the failure.

Comment: It appears you have the `BRACE_CCL` option set in your shell, which causes `{0}` to be treated as a character class containing one character, rather than being treated literally.

Comment: nice find, thanks chepner, `unsetopt BRACE_CCL` fixed it for good. Must be some preset in YADR.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is generally better to quote strings that contain `{...}` sequences (e.g., `git checkout 'stash@{0}' ...`), because they are subject to [brace expansion](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Brace-Expansion).
(Or, for that matter, single-quote *any* string literal you want to preserve *as is*.)

However, in a ***default* `zsh` environment**  this **would *not* be a problem**, because **`{0}` is not a valid brace expression** and is therefore simply printed as is (equally applies to `bash`, `dash`, and `ksh`); verify with:

```
echo stash@{0}  # prints as is in bash, dash, ksh, zsh (with default options in effect)
```

Kudos to [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for suspecting that the **`BRACE_CLL` `zsh` option may be set**, which indeed does produce the symptom:

```
$ setopt BRACE_CCL
$ echo stash@{0}
stash@0          # !! braces removed
```

As chepner states, `BRACE_CCL` "causes `{0}` to be treated as a character class containing one character, rather than being treated literally"; in other words: `BRACE_CCL` expands *each individual character* inside `{...}` (e.g., `echo a{01}` -> `a0 a1`) and with just *one* character specified, the net effect is *removal* of the enclosing braces.

As the OP himself has since confirmed, `unsetopt BRACE_CCL` solved the problem.

Comment: My pleasure; kudos to @chepner for solving the mystery.

Comment: I needed to do something to make up for my train wreck of a previous answer :)