# git stash apply @stash{x} not working for me

Tags: git

I am trying to apply a specific stash using:

```
git stash apply stash@{2}
```

But end up with this error:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@': unknown revision or path not in
>   the working tree.

I have plenty of stashed entries, over 20 if I do a **git stash list**

I am unsure what this error is trying to tell me, can someone advise further? Thanks

Comment: Most likely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30030812/using-curly-braces-referencing-git-revisions-references-fails

Answer (score 105):

You need to quote the string, because your shell is eating the content of the `{}` as an expansion. So use `git stash apply 'stash@{2}'`. Alternatively you can use the SHA of the stash, or next time when you apply it, you can name the stash yourself.