# How to see git stash modification when it was done by git stash push filename

Tags: git, powershell, git-stash

I stash few files earlier by git stash push file_path. Now I can see them as list as by 
git stash list

```
stash@{0}: WIP on web_09_11: a6c038e7 Merged PR 25503: Get latst commites
stash@{1}: WIP on web_09_11: a6c038e7 Merged PR 25503: Get latst commites
stash@{2}: WIP on web_09_11: a6c038e7 Merged PR 25503: Get latst commites
stash@{3}: WIP on web_09_11: a6c038e7 Merged PR 25503: Get latst commites
```

I want to see the content of each stash. I found that it should show if I try

> git stash show stash@{1}
>
> But it gives me error as:
>   fatal: ambiguous argument 'stash@': unknown
>   revision or path not in the working tree. Use '--' to separate paths
>   from revisions, like this:
>
> Or Too many revisions specified: 'stash@' 'MQA=' 'xml' 'text'

how can I see it?

Comment: Looks like your shell is eating the braces. This seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468893/stash1-is-ambiguous

Comment: Possible duplicate of [stash@{1} is ambiguous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468893/stash1-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a shell issue : use quotes around `'stash@{xx}'`

```
git show 'stash@{1}'
```

---

In Powershell for example : `{ cmd1; cmd2 }` defines a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7)

Here is an example of what I get :

```
> echo stash@{1}
stash@
1
> echo 'stash@{1}'
stash@{1}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using PowerShell posh git extension.  This worked nicely.

Comment: To see only the file name I used git stash show 'stash@{1}'  if u don't want to see the modified content.